# Android SDK installation doesn't find JDK

Tags: java, android, sdk, windows-7-x64, jdk6

I'm trying to install the Android SDK on my Windows 7 x64 System.

`jdk-6u23-windows-x64.exe` is installed, but the **Android SDK** setup refuses to proceed because it doesn't find the **JDK** installation.

Is this a known issue? And is there a solution?

[image: SDK Error]

Comment: What do you mean by "the Android-SDK-Setup refuses to proceed"? AFAIK, installing android-sdk_r07-windows.zip is simply unzipping it to a folder (e.g. C:\android-sdk-windows) and appending that folder to the %PATH% environment variable. Please clarify, so that we can help you better.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with installer_r08-windows.exe (which is the "recommended" download). Setting JAVA_HOME doesn't seem to help. I suppose I'll try the zip file next...

Comment: @AndroidEve: The Android SDK (maybe not the ADT) for Windows is an EXE file, for example installer_r22.0.1-windows.exe

Comment: I marked Lazarus- comment as useful, but it isn't! That solution won't work on Windows 8!

Comment: the solution from Jules Colle + setting JAVA_HOME environment is working on my Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: Simplest way, open tools/android.bat file, find the line says "set java_exe", change it to "set java_exe=ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_YOUR_JAVA_EXE" and comment out the two following lines;

Comment: @Jurgen's answer is wrong. Silly Back-Next just doesn't work

Comment: Related: [Android SDK doesn't find JDK](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28512126/2947415)

Comment: Its' such a shame that an official compiler contain such basic bugs.

Comment: This solution works perfectly for me:
[Click Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11430824/1666800)

Answer (score 1258):

Press ***Back*** when you get the notification and then ***Next***. This time it will find the `JDK`.

Comment: Wah I re-downloaded JDK installer on my slow line only to realise that I DO HAVE JDK installed!  And this worked thanks!

Comment: This is a pretty weird bug to say the least. It popped up on a workstation but not my desktop.

Comment: It looks like cache the test result, and even so after restar the computer you must start setup, forward till this step, press back, and press next again. For windows 7 x64, there is a registry fix: searching for Windows 7 x64 Registry Android, is possible to find it.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Windows 7 x64. I'm not joking. I set JAVA_HOME and I tried clicking back and next several times, but it's still not working. Neither does running SDK Manager.exe from the archive and I am positive I have JDK 7 installed (even ran the installer again and it told me it's already installed).

Comment: @f.ardelian, take a look at my answer (just posted it). it worked for me, it might for you

Comment: Not a working fix for Windows 7 x64, suggest an edit to the answer to make that clear.

Comment: Sadly the fix isn't working on 7 x64 JDK 7 and last Android SDK

Comment: I've tried setting JAVA_HOME to `[...]system32/java.exe`, `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin\java.exe` and just `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09` but the installer still doesn't recognise it. I have tried going back nad forth as descirbed several times. Also useing `Win7 64bit`

Comment: I don't know if Windows 8 is the relevant factor, but it certainly doesn't work on my Windows 8 machine.

Comment: Setting `JAVA_HOME` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17` worked for me (of course you need to restart the installer for changes in environment variables to take effect; back and forth won't work for that).

Comment: After I installed JDK6 and set JAVA_HOME to `C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.6.0_45`, then the installer picked up JDK7.  Android SDK docs do say that JDK 6 is required - http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html.  This was on Win 7 Pro 64bit.

Comment: after setting JAVA_HOME, end install program and try rerun several times, it works!

Comment: does not work for me, even installed java fresh - but of course not to C drive which is prob why the POS doesnt get found.

Comment: It is not a valid solution anymore, gotta find out something new :/

Comment: This just worked for me on Win 7 x64.  Had to enter a VALID path, hit Next, get the error, go back, go Next again, leave the path completely blank, then Next again.  Works for me.

Comment: For windows 7 x86. If you installed the java jdk while the android studio is open, try closing the android studio installer and try again. It immediately detected the jdk so seems to be fine with me.

Comment: I had the same problem but my JAVA_HOME was pointing to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin; I changed it to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79 and now it works - Running W7 - X64

Comment: Didn't work for me. So, I closed and reopened the setup. Then it worked.

Answer (score 284):

Actual SETUP:

- **OS**: Windows 8.1
- **JDK** file: jdk-8u11-windows-x64.exe
- **ADT** file: installer_r23.0.2-windows.exe

Install the `x64 JDK`, and try the back-next option first, and then try setting `JAVA_HOME` like the error message says, but if that doesn't work for you either, then try this:

Do as it says, set `JAVA_HOME` in your environment variables, but in the path use forward slashes instead of backslashes.

Seriously.

For me it failed when `JAVA_HOME` was `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31` but worked fine when it was `C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_31` - drove me nuts!

If this is not enough, also add to the beginning of the Environment Variable `Path`  **%JAVA_HOME%;**

Updated values in System Environment Variables:

- `JAVA_HOME=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_11`
- `JRE_HOME=C:/Program Files/Java/jre8`
- `Path=%JAVA_HOME%;C:...`

Comment: YES!!! this one worked for my win 7 pro 64 bit install with android r18 exe installer. You, sir, are my hero for today. Now I just need to know how on earth you thought to even try that? :-)

Comment: I guessed that the likely Windows haters that coded this never bothered to actually test it, and their Unix forwardslashes weren't converted to Windows backslashes.

Comment: Almost gave up because NOTHING was working, including this solution.

My problem however was I was trying to be too smart! I had JAVA_HOME set to C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_03/BIN but you DON'T need to include the /bin!!! Just remove it and you'll be good!

Comment: Remembering to restart the installer after adding the ENV Variable.

Comment: Another tip: I've gotten into the habit of ending with ';', in case I want to add another address later - don't do that here.

Comment: all right my fault is appending a semicolon to JAVA_HOME. remove it. win7 x86_64.

Comment: Strangely, when I set the JAVA_HOME from forward-slashes Java 6 JDK, it finally found my Java 7 JDK... :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing the problem with the slashes out! I had exactly the same problem!

Comment: Amazing!!! They seriously should do something about this dumb forward slash problem!

Comment: Setting the JAVA_HOME worked for me under Win8 (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10). Dont forget to reboot after setting the JAVA_HOME

Comment: back-next wasn't needed in my case, forward slashes fixed the issues (win 7 x64 ultimate)

Comment: this one worked for me on Windows 8.1 RTM, most voted answer (press back and next again) didnt work

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 8.1, on next step I got full path to java like this C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe!

Comment: Mine worked with `backward slashes(\)` but I had to put a `backward slash(\)` at the end of the path even, for example C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\

Comment: Awesome. I tried all other ways but nothing works until I tried this "silly" trick. Works brilliantly on Windows 7 x64

Comment: I added the path to the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. The back/next trick didn't work for me, but **restarting the installer executable did**.

Comment: This works on Win8 x64. Close the installer and restart it after messing with PATH and JAVA_HOME !

Comment: Works on Win10 x64. ths sooooo much.

Answer (score 99):

I found the solution and it's beautifully stupid. I found *[Android SDK cannot detect JDK](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-sdk-cannot-detect-jdk.html)*.

Press the ***Back*** button on the SDK error screen that tells you that the EXE couldn't detect the JDK. Then press ***Next***.

Who would have thought that would happen?

Comment: Doesn't help on win7 64bit.

Answer (score 88):

It seems like it doesn't work without 32 bit JDK.
Just install it and be happy...

Comment: Hmmm... I did the same but it didn't work for me. Perhaps there is an additional step that needs to be done?

Comment: I have actually just had the same problem with the 32 bit JDK

Comment: I'm trying to install the Android SDK with "installer_r20-windows" and it *STILL* refuses to accept the 64bit JDK as legitimate, even after setting the JAVA_HOME env. var. GOOGLE: FIX IT !!

Comment: I had installed the Java SDK x64. It appears the Android SDK is x32. Nice one google, can you be clearer next time?

Comment: Worked for me, Win7 64bit. Tried the other solutions to no avail.

Answer (score 32):

I downloaded the .zip archive instead and ran `SDK Manager.exe`, and it worked like a charm. You had the same issue with the .exe otherwise.

Answer (score 28):

Warning: As a commenter mentioned, don't try this on a Windows 7! I tested it with Windows XP 64 bit.

As the posted solution does NOT work for all (including me, myself, and I), I want to leave a note for those seeking for another way (without registry hacking, etc.) to solve this on a Windows 64 bit system. Just add PATH (capital letters!!) to your environment Variables and set the value to your JDK-Path.

I added JDK to the existing "Path" which did not work, like it didn't with JAVA_HOME or the "Back"-Solution. Adding it to "PATH" finally did the trick.

I hope this might be helpful for somebody.

Comment: I've tried all the other answers, except for this one. I'll give this a shot and report back in a couple of days.

Comment: check, right.. old and simple java class path variable ;=)))))) ps.: thx, found it via google and wanted to post it myself.. :) the dialog actually say you should do it ;) nobody reads today

Comment: Back button trick didn't worked for me, but adding PATH worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: It seems that environment variable names are case insensitive on Windows 7, so when I added a 'PATH' variable it overwrote the 'Path' variable. Just a warning for anyone else who tries the same thing!

Comment: Oh, thats quite bad, i will add a warning to my answer.

Comment: This is what worked for me (tried all the others too). This will be my first experience developing with Java/Android. Doesn't exactly feel me with confidence that this will be a pain free experience when the installer is a **JOKE** :|

Comment: Still didn't work for me, wonder what is wrong :( I already have the Path variable, I changed it to PATH and appended my jdk path "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin" to it (w/o the quotes), then tried to install android sdk, still wouldn't proceed :(

Comment: This worked for me, with one extra step. I had to rename the java.exe file in c:\windows\system32 to something else (java.exe.old for me). This made it actually check the JDK directory, and it was able to resolve it.

Comment: Everything else failed on Win7 64 bits, I was like ok I give up but let me give this last shot. And then it worked like magic...thanks

Comment: @IronicMuffin this worked for me on 64 bit Windows w/ 64 bit JDK.

Answer (score 20):

All you need are the following two registry entries. It appears as if whoever posted the other registry stuff basically just copied all the keys from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft` into `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft`,
which obviously isn't an ideal solution because most of the keys aren't needed.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit]
"CurrentVersion"="1.6"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.6]
"JavaHome"="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_23"
```

Answer (score 20):

Non of these solutions worked for me. I fixed it by temporarily changing the filename of `C:\Windows\System32\java.exe` to `java_.exe`

Comment: This worked in my 64 bit windows 7 with jdk7x64bit and the 20.0.3 installer

Comment: WOW! Worked perfect under `Windows 7 x64` without `32-bit JDK`! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me. Crazy - what gives with all this bugginess for installing these tools on Windows?

Answer (score 19):

None of the solutions here worked for the `64-bit` version.

Putting the `JDK` path before the `c:\windows\system32\` path in your environment variables solves the problem. Otherwise the `32-bit` **`java.exe`** is found before the `64-bit JDK` version.

Comment: Too many java's in the path I suppose... Shouldn't it be the same java.exe in both cases though?

Comment: @SeanJA there are cases where you have java installed as 32 bit and 64 bit and you have to make sure it points at first to the 64 bit version

Comment: I didn't think java would be installed by default on a new windows machine... but there I go assuming again...

Comment: This solution worked for Windows8 x64. Tried everything else above with no luck.

Answer (score 17):

After reading a couple of blog posts, it does seem to be even an easier fix by clicking ***BACK*** when the installer says couldn't find the JDK, and then simply click ***NEXT*** again and magically it finds the JDK. No registry messing around or re-downloading etc..

Answer (score 15):

Adding JAVA_HOME environment variable (under **System Variables**) did the trick for me. 
Clicking "Back" and "Next" buttons didn't work.

Windows 7 Professional x64, JDK 1.7.0_04 (64 bit, I don't have x86 version installed)

I think that installer tries to find JDK in specific (1.6?) version and if it can't find it, checks JAVA_HOME which was not set in my case. I have another computer (the same system but with JDK 1.6 x64) and it worked without JAVA_HOME variable.

**You don't have to install 32 bit version of JDK :)**

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me. My value is: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04

Comment: i added C:/Program Files/java/jdk1.7.0 to user variables and set as JAVA-HOME. Worked for me.

Comment: This is the CORRECT way. Works fine for ma machine win7 64 bit. without JDK 32bit.

Answer (score 11):

I copied the Java.exe from

> C:\Windows\System32

to

> C:\Windows\SysWOW64

and it worked.

I'm using 64 bit Windows 8.

Comment: You, sir, are a life saver. Can't believe these ridiculous issues still exist close to a year later

Answer (score 8):

Setting the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to

> `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07`

instead of

> `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin`

fixed it for me.

Comment: This is the one that worked for me. I had already set the environment variable, clicked back and then next, no prevail. This seemed to work.

For anyone else that might be having issues, I'm using Windows 8.1, and Java JDK/JRE 8.  After clicking next, it goes back to /system32/java.exe and says it was found.

Answer (score 8):

The guy above who put this: "I experienced this problem too, but none of the answers helped. What I did, **I removed the last backslash from the JAVA_HOME variable and it started working. Also, remember not to include the bin folder in the path."** This was in fact the correct answer.

For this SDK to install this is what I did. I am running the latest Microsoft OS Windows 8.

**User Variables:**

> Path  `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin`

**Environment Variables**

**Create these two:**

> CLASSPATH `%HOME_JAVA%\jre\lib`
>
> HOME_JAVA `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09`

**This one already exists so just edit:**

> Path At this end of `WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\` simply add "`;C:\Program`
>   `Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09"`

This is what I did and it worked for me. =)

Comment: It worked. I was actually adding `bin` in the `JAVA_HOME` path end as well but removing it worked

Answer (score 7):

This registry fix worked  like a charm on my Windows 7 x64 setup:  http://codearetoy.wordpress.com/2010/12/23/jdk-not-found-on-installing-android-sdk/

Comment: at the bottom, "click back", "click next" the button is now enabled

Answer (score 7):

Press <kbd>Report error</kbd> and <kbd>OK</kbd>. <kbd>Next</kbd> will be enabled.

Answer (score 6):

Try downloading and installing the zipped version rather than the .exe installer.

Comment: this is the biggest pile of crap fix up issue i ever seen.  Its like people are trying hundred different things, one things works here and not there.  Why is this such an issue esp if its from the so called big tech company "Google".  I think they need to invest in fixing up their crap. rather than making autodriving cars and stuff.  My setup still doesnt work.  when i install the SDK it says it has found the JDK in correct folder but then the SDK manager just doesnt open no matter what!  on my other PC works fine. with same setup and machine

Answer (score 6):

Also, **RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR**! Worked for me with backslash fix.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, tried all the solutions but nothing worked. The problem is with Windows 7 installed is 64 bit and all the software that you are installing should be 32 bit. Android SDK itself is 32 bit and it identifies only 32 bit JDK. So install following software.

1. JDK (32 bit)
2. Android SDK (while installing SDK, make sure install it in directory other than "C:\Program Files (x86)", more probably in other drive or in the directory where Eclipse is extracted)
3. Eclipse (32 bit) and finally [ADT](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adt.html).

I tried it and all works fine.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and solved it by installing the x86 version of the JDK (on Windows XP x64).

Comment: You don't have to do this. Check my answer above :)

Answer (score 4):

I experienced this problem too, but none of the answers helped. What I did, I removed the last backslash from the JAVA_HOME variable and it started working. Also, remember not to include the bin folder in the path.

Answer (score 4):

Android SDK is 32 bit app, and it requires the 32 bit of JDK to work... the 64 bit JDK won't make any use for it...

Answer (score 4):

**WORKING SOLUTION AND NO REGISTRY MODIFY NEEDED**

Simply put your java bin path in front of your PATH environment.

PATH before

```
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\%^^&^&^............(old path setting)
```

PATH after

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\%^^&^&^............(old path setting)
```

And now the Android SDK installer is working.

BTW, I'm running Win7 x64.

Answer (score 4):

1-Simply done the "JAVA_HOME" environment variable thing.

2-Right-Click on Android SDK and from compatibletiy Tab Select windows 7 and administrator.

3-Run it again.

Answer (score 3):

For installer_r21.1-windows.exe on Windows 8 x 64 what worked for me was setting up my user environment variable JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10.
Hope this helps you all! :)

Answer (score 2):

Yeah install the 32 bit version of the Java SE SDK (or any of the combinations). That should help solve your problem.

Comment: See the "back and forward" answer. That's the solution. Forget playing with the registry or installing the 32bit.

Comment: @llappall It doesn't work in some cases. Read my answer above ;)

Answer (score 2):

The above methods did not work for me in Windows 8 Pro.

Just set the path to

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\
```

Where C is your drive in which you have installed the JDK.

Don't forget the backward slash at the end.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running a 64-bit version of Windows 7 and I was getting this issue when attempting to install Android Studio 1.0 using the executable from:

http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html

I tried all the listed solutions and several different versions of JDK 1.7 and 1.8 -- no dice. I went with installing the zipped version of the application and it worked like a charm:

http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest

Still baffled by this problem; especially since beta versions of Android Studio worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

**4 Different Solutions:**

**1)** If you get above screen, just click `BACK` button and from previous screen click `NEXT` button. Actually silly, but sounds good.

**2)** [Download SDK Manager](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html) **`.zip`** format instead of **`.exe`** and then try to install. It’s all so silly, but work like a charm.

**3)** If you installed **64 bit** JDK means, just uninstall that and install 32-bit JDK.

**4)**  You have to change that as following,

```
JAVA_HOME=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_11
JRE_HOME=C:/Program Files/Java/jre8
Path=%JAVA_HOME%;C:…
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to download the 32-bit SDK version because Win7 64-bit is not supported only Windows Server 2003 has a supported 64-bit version.  During the download of Java SDK pick "Windows" as your platform and not "Windowsx64".
Once I did this android SDK installed like a charm.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope. Just do the back-and-forward as explained above.

Comment: no i have a pc where i uninstalled ALL jave jdk and jre installs, then installed ONLY 64 but JDK and JRE .  and the SDK Manager worked with no probs.  on my other PC i used same method and no it does not work

Answer (score 1):

For Windows users:

You would set JAVA_HOME environment variable: http://wso2.org/project/wsas/java/1.1/docs/setting-java-home.html

Answer (score 1):

I tried several posted solutions and then it took a system reboot before it started working, which may have been because I had just installed the JDK.  Here are all the things I had going on - not sure which ones were essential:

- 64-bit JDK installed.
- JAVA_HOME defined using forward slashes (/) instead of backslashes
  ().
- JDK 'bin' directory listed at *beginning* of PATH.
- System reboot.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed on SDK revision 20.xxx

Download it via http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r20.0.3-windows.exe

Comment: Not true, currently running that installer with a windows 7 64bit and 64bit jdk7.0 and it still doesn't work. None of the fixes in this thread do.

Comment: It worked for me some how. Maybe you having a different issue.

Comment: No it hasn't. I've just installed installer_r22.0.1-windows.exe on Windows 7 64-bit with 64-bit JDK and I had to go through the various contortions on this thread before I found the right combination that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to restart your machine. For me, without having to use forward slashes it worked after I restarted windows.

Answer (score 1):

Install both `JDK 64 bit 1.6 for Windows` and `JRE 1.7 64bit for Windows`.

It worked in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I spent a little over an hour trying just about every option presented.  I eventually figured out that I had a lot of stale entries for software that I had uninstalled.  I deleted all the registry nodes that had any stale data (pointed to the wrong directory).  This included the

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Runtime
>   Environment]

and

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment]

entries as a JRE included in the JDK.

I also got rid of all the JAVA entries in my environmental variables.  I guess I blame it on bad uninstallers that do not clean up after themselves.

Answer (score 1):

There is too many ways for doing it:

### Way number one

If Java is installed perfectly in your machine, then please close the installer and try to reinstall it.

When you open it for the second time, it will find JAVA.

### Way number 2

Set up an environment variable like this-

> [Environment variables for java installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation/1672536#1672536)

And then try again.

It should work :)

Answer (score 0):

It is bug in the Android installer. Download the latest installer and try it. Then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was in JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS environment variable. Nothing helps me until I removed it. Hope it help someone!

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that i run studio.exe instead of studio64.exe. I'm running Windows 8 64bits

Answer (score 0):

For Wine users:...
For reasons having to do with "unimplemented" (as in: the "find" command and the "/D" switch to "copy"), it appears that you have to cheat a bit more to get Android SDK to see JDK in Wine.

However, I have passed the hurdles and am (I suppose) obliged to share something (anything) that worked:

1. What is responsible for finding Java is the script "tools/lib/find_java.bat". In the beginning of that file, add:

   set java_exe=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java.exe
      goto :EOF

   2. To circumvent the "copy /D not implemented" issue, in "tools/android.bat" comment out (with "rem") the lines from just after

   :MkTempCopy

to just before

```
:EndTempCopy
```

You should now (if you've set JAVA_HOME) be able to run android.bat and install the SDK parts you need.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 running the x64 SDK.

1. Download the latest JDK from here: [Oracle JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)
2. Once downloaded and extracted go into the JDK file at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin and double click on the java Application file (it's the only one called just **java**). This will briefly open the command line.
3. Begin the process of installing Android Studio again, from scratch. It should automatically detect the SDK now.

For whatever reason Android Studio wouldn't detect it no matter what I put in manually or searched using the browse option.

Pressing back would not work.

Reporting the error would not work.

Adding JAVA_HOME or other suggestions to the C:... would not work.

It was only beginning the installation of Android Studio again *after* running the java file that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have the jdk installed on my D: drive. None of the other answers worked for me. I got it to install by creating a symbolic link from the C: drive to the installed location:

```
    c:
    cd "Program Files"
    mklink /d Java "d:\Program Files\Java"
```

Note that the jdk (and jre) install directories are subdirectories of "Java" so upgrading is not a problem even though the name changes with the release.

Answer (score 0):

I add the following in the users Environment Variable( Windows 10)

```
JAVA_HOME=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_11
JRE_HOME=C:/Program Files/Java/jre8
Path=%JAVA_HOME%;C:...
```

And then cancel the current installation of Android Studio and start again. It worked fine this time for me. No JDK error.

Answer (score 0):

While this question has already been answered.
Here is what exact steps you need to do when you are setting up for development. In general anything related to Java Development.

**Setting Up Java**

Make sure you are using latest jdk url

```
curl -L -O -H "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" -k "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u60-b27/jdk-8u60-linux-x64.tar.gz"
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_67/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_67/bin/javac" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_67/bin/javaws" 1
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
sudo update-alternatives --config javaws
```

**Setting up your system in this case ubuntu/mac**

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/ashish/android-sdks
export ANDROID_SDK=/home/ashish/android-sdks
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_45
export JDK_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_45/
export JRE_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_45/jre
export PATH=$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
```

this contents needs to appear in **.profile** in ubuntu or **.bash_profile** in mac in home folder we can go there using `cd ~`