# Installing Android SDK on Windows 7 64-bit: "JDK not found"?

Tags: android, sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android SDK installation doesn't find JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382178/android-sdk-installation-doesnt-find-jdk)

I am unable to install the android SDK.  It requests that I have the JDK, which I do.  I re-downloaded and reinstalled the Java JDK.  I restarted my computer, I ran this install again for the android SDK... nothing... it won't let me get past this point.  Here is a screen shot of the screen I'm stuck on:

[image: http://imgur.com/xAcw5.jpg]

I've googled my problem, I've spent 2 hours trying to find the answer... the closest I could get would be something about adding a "Path" to my "Environment Variables."  I found where the environment variables are in Windows 7, but I don't have the slightest clue what I am supposed to do.

Comment: Did you install the 32bit or 64bit JDK?

Comment: I installed the 64-bit JDK, because my machine and OS are 64-bit.  However, I tried installing 32-bit JDK, and now I got past that screen and am now able to install it.  Still haven't had time all week to try to make a simple app and see if I can run the Android Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 16):

Found this last night [Android SDK install problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394584/android-sdk-install-problem) and now I can install it on my Win7 64bit + JDK 64bit

Somehow the r8 SDK installer are looking for JDK path inside 32bit registry key while I am installing 64bit JDK.

**Update**
Believe it or not, clicking Back and Next will fix it :) (someone comment on my blog post about it and judging from the others comments, it kind of works)

Disclaimer: This is my blog http://codearetoy.wordpress.com/2010/12/23/jdk-not-found-on-installing-android-sdk/

Comment: Back and Next worked!!! Ha-ha!!!

Comment: It is, and the weird thing is Google doesn't fix it from 8 months ago

Comment: that's bizarre!  I've never seen anything broken quite like that before

Answer (score 4):

I have this same problem on my new PC, and now I found this and it works:

Windows 7:

1. From the desktop, right click the Computer icon.
2. Choose Properties from the context menu.
3. Click the Advanced system settings link.
4. Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find
   the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH
   environment variable does not exist, click New.
5. In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, **SET
   the value of the PATH environment variable TO JAVA_HOME**. Click OK. Close all
   remaining windows by clicking OK.

Then it will have no problem on installing the Android sdk
Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Answer (score 3):

I've always installed Java JDK 32-bit from [here.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
Seems to be the easiest way, works properly, and I don't really see why one would need 64-bit when doing Android programming.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but I found a way to fix it. When you get that box go and download it again; after it has downloaded, go back to the pop up box and hit the back button and then click next again and it should recognize that you have the JDK installed.
Hope this helps, and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

you got to download jdk basic from oracle.com i was getting that too. visit that site and it will take you straight there. scroll down and to the first jdk/jre download the correct system type. install it and sdk should pop up after it done.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the 64bit version of JDK from this site

https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewProductDetail-Start?ProductRef=jdk-6u23-oth-JPR@CDS-CDS_Developer
I had no problems installing android

Comment: I believe this is the same site that I used.  I just installed the 32-bit version just because I thought "what the heck, I've tried everything." and it worked.  I was able to install the android SDK.