# Android SDK install: Java SE development Kit (JDK) not found

Tags: android, sdk, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android SDK installation doesn't find JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382178/android-sdk-installation-doesnt-find-jdk)

I have installed Java runtime 6 to `C:\src\libraries\jre6`.

I installed Java JDK to `C:\src\libraries\javasdk`.

My %PATH% is set to:

> PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\system32
>   \WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\src\libraries\javasdk\bin;C:\src\libraries\javasdk;C:
>   \src\libraries\javasdk\jdk\bin;C:\src\libraries\javasdk\jdk;C:\src\libraries\jav
>   asdk;

When I run the Android SDK installer I get the error:

> "Java SE development Kit (JDK) not found"

I'm at a loss as to what the Android SDK cannot really find.

Answer (score 127):

Windows 7 32 bit has the same behaviour as Windows XP SP3. Hit BACK and then NEXT again and you're able to install the Android SDK.

Comment: Strangely, this worked on my machine!

Comment: Same here, Windows Vista Home Premium

Comment: Why on earth does this work?

Comment: XP Pro SP3 32 bit, same problem. This works fine.

Comment: The force is strong with this one

Comment: This works on my machine with win 7 x64 . But how? :-)

Comment: Yes worked for me. What a joke! Surely something like that wouldn't be hard to fix. Just lost time reinstalling, rebooting :(

Comment: Lovely. Never had to do this on my 64bit machine. Perhaps a 32bit bug?

Comment: at the beginning I thought it was a joke.. but it works :)

Comment: Makes me wonder how high the level of your frustration were before you found THAT out.

Comment: This is not working on 7 x64 with x64 JDK

Answer (score 10):

The answer is bang on, but some clarification that might help some not familiar with registry editing (like me).

1. Run regedit.
2. Find [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit]
3. Right click on the key and click export, then save the file to the desktop.
4. Right click then click edit.
5. Add Wow6432Node to the path of each key in the file.  See above (@Rog_enk) for an example.  Save.
6. Back in regedit, click File->Import and select the file from above.  Done.
7. Try the SDK installer again.

Comment: by what name shoul the imported key shoul be saved???

Comment: see above for a better answer (the BACK and NEXT solution)

Comment: Need more clarification because the back and next solution isn't working anymore!

Comment: OK.  Can you be specific?  Which SDK?

Comment: I just had to do this now [Sep '12] and this answer was posted Jan '11.. WTF..

Comment: did @dge's back/next solution not work?

Answer (score 8):

On Windows 7 x64 the Android SDK Installer is looking for the JDK in the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft` registry branch.

But in reality the JavaSoft entry was placed in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft`. I copied all JavaSoft branch to the path search, and then the installer found the JDK.

Answer (score 7):

Just press back, then next and it will find it. [Android SDK installation doesn't find JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382178/android-sdk-installation-doesnt-find-jdk)

Answer (score 6):

Windows 7 64 bit - same behaviour as windows XP SP3 and Windows 7 32 bit: Just set `JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_14` or whatever your actual path, start SDK, and after you'll get error  - hit BACK and than NEXT again and you're able to install the Andriod SDK

Answer (score 0):

It seems that creating and setting my environment variable, `CLASSPATH`, to `C:\src\libraries\jre6\lib` fixed my problem.  I downloaded the Android SDK zip file, put it where I wanted it.  I was able to proceed from there.