# Installing SDK but it refuge cause of missing java - Installed but stil the same, even restarted the installation

Tags: java, sdk, installation

Hi i was about to install Android SDK Tool when a screen said "Java SE Development Kit" wasn`t installed, OK so i installed it "Java Development Kit Version 6 Update 23" but the screen stil say its not installed, do i need to restart my computer? its said go to java.sun.com bla bla before continued, nothing about restart the computer, hae restarted the installation but stil the same.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Java JDK is in your PATH (Right-click Computer, select Properties, Advanced System Settings, Environment) and then re-try the installation.

Also look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394584/android-sdk-install-problem).