# Reinstalling Android development tools--now getting Failed to load the JNI shared library

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Going back to develop on Android. Eclipse wasn't downloading the 2.3 SDK, so I decided to just reinstall everything.

I found I needed the 32 bit version of Java SE sdk, jdk-6u23-windows-i586.exe from Oracle's web site.

Downloaded eclipse and put it in the programs directory, but when I try to run Eclipse now I get the error message "Failed to load the JNI shared library c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin\client\jvm.dll. The jdk installer didn't create a bin\client directory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed to load the JNI shared Library (JDK)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352493/failed-to-load-the-jni-shared-library-jdk)

Comment: It's duplicate. There are a lot of topic with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Searching the internet revealed the Android tools installer doesn't like 64 bit Java and Eclipse. I switched back to the 32-bit Java, but still had 64 bit Eclipse installed.

The tool installer runs, but it isn't updating Eclipse now.

Comment: doh--forgot the install ADT step: http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing

Answer (score 0):

I myself am running x64 Eclipse and JDK, and can update the Android SDK and Eclipse plug-ins just fine.

Also note that in build 23, jvm.dll should be at a location like C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\server\jvm.dll. Your error looks like a path/classpath misconfiguration.

You should check your paths and classpaths after doing a re-install.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394584/android-sdk-install-problem on how to get the SDK installer to run with 64 bit JDK. I'm lazy and just went with 32-bit versions.