# Android SDK deosn't think JDK is installed? - Windows 7

Tags: android, windows, sdk, java

On Windows 7 I have installed the Java SE JDK, then rebooted.
[image]

When I then run the Android SDK installer, there is a warning that the JDK is not installed.

[image]

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394584/android-sdk-install-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that if I press the Back button on the Android SDK installer, then press the Next button again, it works!

Comment: This question does (basically) duplicate another, but this is a different solution. Please accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Did you install 32-bit version or 64-bit version?

Check out here for Windows 7 / Android Tools setup :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588548/help-jdk-not-detected-problem-during-android-sdk-tools-setup

Also, check out your PATH environment variables to confirm JDK is setup and referenced!

And as commented below, also check out JAVA_HOME variable.

Comment: This is a good debugging tip Dominic. I did find that the Back, Next trick did it for me. Looks like a bug in the Android installer.

Comment: I had the same problem, turns out I did not have JAVA_HOME set for some reason (x64 JDK on Win7). I set the variable and restarted the Android SDK install, and it worked fine. So I'd mention JAVA_HOME in addition to PATH.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem, tried all the solutions but nothing worked. The problem is with Windows 7 installed is 64 bit and all the softwares that you are installing should be 32 bit.
Android SDK itself is 32 bit and it identifies only 32 bit JDK. So install following softwares.

1. JDK (32 bit)
2. Android SDK (while installing SDK, make sure install it in directory other than "C:\Program Files (x86)", more probably in other drive or in the directory where Eclipse is extracted)
3. Eclipse (32 bit) and finally ADT.

i tried it and all works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You Should Create an Environment Variable to Point to Your java Directory.
Go to My Computer > right click on a free space > choose properties > in the left column choose "Advance System Setting" > Go to Advance tab > push Environment variable button > in System Variable click on New :

Variable name : JAVA_HOME
Variable value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06

You should be careful about path if you add path like this "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\bin" or this one "C:\Program Files\Java" it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

My is configuration Windows 7 64-bit.

I didn't want to uninstall 64-bit jdk and the other suggestions weren't working. So I just downloaded the 32-bit and re-ran the windows installer.

Voila, it works and doesn't take the 32-bit either. It takes the 64-bit higher version instead.

I feel it just feels safe with the presence of the 32-bit jdk :P

Answer (score 0):

When you downloaded sdk, running via browser's downloaded files section right? application can't detect java in this state. if you run it via directly its own folder, it will find sdk. simple