# Android SDK can't find JDK

Tags: java, android, sdk

I know this have been asked many of times before but i've read through all of the answers for this problem yet i haven't been able to solve this issue.

My installer finds the JDK (never had the problem of it not finding it) but after the install process when it want's to download libraries a cmd looking window pops up in the background and a window telling me to add a certain path to the "Path" variable shows up.
I do as it says but still the same problem.

I've tried both x86 and 64x jdk's and jre's but nothing seems to fix this. When i had the x86 jdk installed it couldn't find the jdk and the back-next trick wouldn't fix it.
I've also tried editing the registry like shown in this topic:
[Android SDK install problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394584/android-sdk-install-problem)
but that didn't change anything (also, the changes doesn't appear in the export of the key i make after importing the one with the changes.)

Any help is greatly appreciated as i've tried to install this for months now
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was also having this problem but fortunatly I found the answer in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588548/help-jdk-not-detected-problem-during-android-sdk-tools-setup/6051580#6051580

I know it's kinda late, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

As of July 27th, using:

```
installer_r22.0.4-windows
jdk-7u25-windows-x64
```

Some say this problem is solved by replacing the "\" with "/", but that doesn't work. Some say uninstall x64 and install x86: not necessary.

I solved this problem creating the `JAVA_HOME` variable with the following path:

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25"

You have to include the double quotes, but you don't have to include the "bin" directory.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, in relation to Michael Petrotta's comment, including \bin in the JAVA_HOME environment variable will still cause even the latest version (installer_r22.0.5-windows) to fail to detect java.exe

**Removing the \bin from the JAVA_HOME variable actually solved the issue on three separate machines I was trying to install the SDK on, and the SDK installed successfully**

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem when i typed in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin` for `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. It should just be `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05` whitout the `\bin`.

*And then the Android SDK installer will prompt you with this message:*

> Android SDK relies on the Java SE Development Kit (JDK).  Java SE
>   Development Kit (JDK) version 1.8 has been found.
>
> Location: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java.exe

Answer (score 0):

for success must follow this steps:

1: installed you java update v.xx
2: installed you java jdk v.xx same as step 1
3: be sure you don't have other version of older installed if yes unistall
4: start installing your android sdk 
5: when install stop to the java can't find go C:\Windows\System32 and find app start with java*
6: delete them in total 3 file 
7: back to sdk intall and next 
for me worked 1000%