# Android SDK not installing on win 7 64-bit

Tags: java, android

I am trying to install Android SDK on windows 7 64-bit but it doesn't work. I keep getting [this screen](http://goo.gl/4Xe5I):

```
JAVA SE Development Kit (JDK) not found.  
Error: Failed to find Java version for 'C:\Windows\system32\java.exe': [2] The system cannot find the file specified.  (...)   
If you believe you have a JDK installed and it was not properly recognized, simply set an environment variable JAVA_HOME to point to it.
```

I tried setting `JAVA_HOME` to `C:\Windows\System32\java.exe` (which is my install path) and it still doesn't work.

In the command line i tested the version with `java -version` and it works perfectly.

Tried the old trick of back and next but sadly doesn't work.

this is so disappointing.... any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate: [Installing Android SDK on Windows 7 64-bit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4384433/1048330)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's *JDK*, not *Java*, it's missing.
JAVA_HOME shouldn't point to the java.exe file. It should point to the jdk-folder.
Typically `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23` or similar. 
If you haven't got a jdk-folder somewhere, you should install **JDK** from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Note that the [official requirement](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) for <strike>developing for Android is JDK 6.</strike>

Answer (score 6):

Setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable in System variable to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\ did solve my problem.

A couple of points to note:

1. No need to specify bin or jre folder name.
2. You will need to cancel and restart the android sdk installation. Previous/Next may not work.
3. I just copied the folder name from Windows explorer address bar. No need to replace the \ with /.

Answer (score 1):

A change in one of the batch files since release 16 of the Android Tools SDK is probably the culprit. Try the ZIP file instead of the EXE. Download android-sdk_r18-windows.zip from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html. Unzip to a new Android directory where your program files normally reside (other locations should also work). Replace find_java.bat in the Android\android-sdk\tools\lib directory with the one from the release 16 SDK tools (if you haven't got it get it from https://tekeye.uk/downloads/find_java.zip). Using the ZIP instead of the EXE means the shortcuts and program groups won't be set up but you can run SDK Manager.exe in the android-sdk folder to grab the rest of the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Download JDK 64bit from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

Add the system variable JAVA_HOME pointing to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21

Answer (score 1):

Here are the setup steps that worked for me starting from scratch (as of today - 6/26/2013)

[Setup Steps]

**Part I - Java JDK**

1. Remove all Java programs installed on PC.
2. Go to: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html (This is Java JDK download site)
3. [http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html]->Mouseclick
4. Select the radio button, , and select and download  and save it into any temporary directory.
5. Mouse click to highlight, jdk-7u25-windows-x64.exe, then right-click-mouse and select  to start installation process and install as default settings.

*Result: Java JDK installation will be completed as expected*

**Part II - Android SDK (Preliminary Setup)**

1. [PC:Home]->mouse-click
2. [PC:Start Menu]->mouse-click
3. [PC:Control Panel]->mouse-click
4. [PC:System]->mouse-click
5. [PC:Advanced system settings]->mouse-click
6. [PC:Environment Variables:System variables]->mouse-click
7. [PC:New System Variable]->Fill in as follows:

   - Variable name : JAVA_HOME
   - Variable value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25
     ->mouse-click
8. Shut down / Restart PC

*This is to make sure the change in environment variable will work*

**Part III - Android SDK**

1. Go to: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
2. [http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html]->mouse-click
3. Download the following and save it into any temporary directory on your PC:

   - installer_r22.0.1-windows.exe (recommended)
4. Mouse-click the downloaded , then right-click-mouse and select  to start installation process and install as default settings.

*Result: Android SDK installation will be completed as expected*

Answer (score 0):

1. Unzip the .exe using 7zip or similar or redownload the .zip
2. Do what the installer would have done: create tools and plugin directories and put the files in `$COMMONFILES` etc into tools and plugins as appropriate
3. Open an (admin?) cmd window
4. CD to `tools/lib`, `notepad find_java.bat`, notice it calls `find_jave.exe` with `-s`.
5. then try `find_java.exe -s`. It will say:
   `Failed to convert path to a short DOS path: C:\Windows\system32\java.exe` (Which is a perfectly short path already - bizarre.)
6. Remove the `-s` from the two calls to `find_java.exe` inside the .bat. Save it
7. Run `/tools/android.bat`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution
I have Windows 7 x64
After installing Java JDK 64bit it didnt work but:
After installing both x32 and x64 it worked :)
Enjoy