# Problem installing Android SDK

Tags: android

I downloaded JDK & Android SDK.
I installed JDK, but when I'm trying to install the Android SDK the installer claims that JDK is not installed.

What can I do?

**Edit:** OS is Win7 32bit

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/q/4382178/779408

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit BACK and then NEXT again and you're able to install the Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Doodle asks an important question, I've run into similar problems when I first upgraded to Win7 64 bit, feeling saucy I put 64 bit Java on, only to find that FF 3.x, which was 32 bit couldn't use it, and I also had problems with Eclipse. You can run both 32 and 64 bit JRE's and JDK's side by side with no problem, so that may fix it. Also, make sure that your JAVA_HOME is set correctly, and that the JDK is properly pointed to by Eclipse in the Window>>Preferences>>Java>>Installed JREs. I know it says JREs, but trust me, everything about Eclipse works better when it points to a JDK and runs from a JDK.

YMMV

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in windows 7, hitting back and next didn't work for me,
 I added JAVA_HOME variable pointing to the jdk folder and added the %JAVA_HOME%\bin to  Path environment.