# Problem Installing Android SDK

Tags: android, installation

I'm trying to install android SDK but it says that I need to install JDK, but the latest jdk is already installed...

I am running win7 Ultimate if it is matter...
What seems to be the problem ?

thnx

Comment: Are you sure that the path to jdk is defined in system/environment variables?

Comment: Isn't this your case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382178/android-sdk-installation-doesnt-find-jdk?

Comment: Worked !!
I pressed back then next and mysteriously it found it !!!

Thanks !! :)

Answer (score 1):

The most common mistake is to believe that the **JDK** is installed when only the **JRE** is. Check for the output of `javac -version`.

Also, you may want to read about setting the `PATH` and the `CLASSPATH` [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

Comment: I know all of that, but trust me this is not this case. I pressed "back" then "forward", and again "next", and it starts running...

Comment: @Master I don't have any reason not to trust you! Glad you got it to work. Hopefully the answer will be useful for somebody else then.