# JDK installation on a separate drive

Tags: android, java

I am trying to use the Android SDK installer and it continually tells me that it cannot find the JDK.  I downloaded and installed the JDK from Sun.  I put the JRE in the following path:

C:\Program Files\Java

And I installed the JDK in this path:

D:\Development_Tools\Java_SE_6

I then proceeded to add this path the PATH variable in the following manner:

D:\Development_Tools\Java_SE_6;other stuff...

The JDK I installed is the 64-bit version.  I have even tried the press "Back" then "Next" trick posted here but it still doesn't work.  I was able to get this all to work on my laptop but there I only have a single drive.  Maybe I have the syntax for changing drives in the PATH variable wrong?  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen this post?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382178/android-sdk-installation-doesnt-find-jdk

Comment: Yes. Didn't work for me. Not sure why.

Comment: @newcomer- Both. Put a copy of the JRE in C:\Program Files and then put the JDK on a separate drive with all my other dev tools and libraries. Just got me first SSD and I'm trying to keep keep it lean by only putting programs/OS on C.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting extra '\' in the PATH i.e D:\Development_Tools\Java_SE_6\;other stuff...

Comment: I did try that and I also tried extending the path to: D:\Development_Tools\Java_SE_6\bin\. Still didn't work so I just downloaded the zip and ran the exe instead. Everything appears to be okay but I won't know until I actually start trying to build something. Thanks for the suggestion though.