# Android SDK says I don't have a JDK, don't I?

Tags: android, sdk, environment-variables, java

I keep getting the message that I should have the JDK installed to be able to install Android SDK, it says a JRE is not enough. The thing is that I have a JDK. These are my environment variables:
CLASSPATH: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\lib
JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0
JRE_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre
PATH: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin

although to my surprise, cmd shows this:
C:\Users\Thiago>java -version
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b147)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode, sharing)

what's going on?

Comment: Have you tried this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382178/android-sdk-installation-doesnt-find-jdk

Answer (score 1):

try to install all 32 bit softwares only. It solved my problem.

Android SDK itself is 32 bit and it identifies only 32 bit JDK. So install following softwares.

1. JDK (32 bit)
2. Android SDK (while installing SDK, make sure install it in directory other than "C:\Program Files (x86)", more probably in other drive or in the directory where Eclipse is extracted)
3. Eclipse (32 bit) and finally ADT.

i tried it and all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer will always search through the PATH env variable in order, so if you also have the location to your JRE before the location to the JDK in your PATH environment variable, then it will always go with the JRE.  Swap their locations around and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a strange issue that may occur while installing the Android SDK on some machines. This may be what you're running into. Here is the solution to it:

[Android SDK installation doesn't find JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382178/android-sdk-installation-doesnt-find-jdk/5115968#5115968)