# Problems Installing Android SDK

Tags: java, android

I have had to install Java and Android on my new machine. I've downloaded `jdk1.6.0_27`. It's installed in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27.

I've set the classpath env var to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\lib and the path var to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\bin. in cmd java - version works fine.

When i try to download Android, it checks to see if java is installed first. It's stating java not installed on my machine. I can't proceed with the Android download. Is there a reason for this?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Duplicate of [Android SDK installation doesn't find JDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382178/android-sdk-installation-doesnt-find-jdk) (and a dozen other questions). Please search first before you post a question; I found the duplicate by searching '[android] problem SDK' without the quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds crazy, but it works.

When that happens: press back, then next. I'm dead serious. It will detect java the second time around. I have no idea why.

As verified here:
[Android SDK installation doesn't find JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382178/android-sdk-installation-doesnt-find-jdk/5115968#5115968)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, tried all the solutions but nothing worked. The problem is with Windows 7 installed is 64 bit and all the software that you are installing should be 32 bit. Android SDK itself is 32 bit and it identifies only 32 bit JDK. So install following software.

1. JDK (32 bit)
2. Android SDK (while installing SDK, make sure install it in directory other than "C:\Program Files (x86)", more probably in other drive or in the directory where Eclipse is extracted)
3. Eclipse (32 bit) and finally ADT.

I tried it and all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `JAVA_HOME` variable defined?  That might help.  On my system I have `JAVA_HOME` set to

```
C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jdk1.6.0_24
```

A little odd perhaps (using the "`~`" dir instead of the "`Program Files`" dir, but seems to help with some older scripts that don't expect to see spaces in the path name.

Comment: hi, is that variable just set to the java install dir?