# Android installation issues

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to set up my android to begin my development lessons all day without success. I have installed the `Java JDK kit` and I'm trying to install the android sdk but this is the error I keep getting all day:

```
"failed to find java version for 'C:\windows\system32\java.exe':[2] The system cannot find the specified file.
```

The Java version I installed is `jdk1.7.0_03`. I have gone to the environment variables and added the path to the java file (`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin` and `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin\javac`) and I still get the same error.
The android sdk version I am trying to install is `"installer_r18-windows.exe"`. Can someone help me?

Comment: I retagged your question from Javascript to Java because the question is about the latter rather than the former. :)

Answer (score 62):

The problem is there are two Java files and the installer picks the first one that it finds; The solution, however, is simple:

rename `c:\windows\system\java.exe` to `c:\windows\system\java.exe.orj`, then restart the installer, and everything should be fine.

It will now use the version of java.exe installed in Program Files\Java instead which solves the issue.

Comment: fix worked for when I was installing Android SDK on Windows 8 Release Preview. +1

Comment: setting JAVA_HOME wasn't enough; had to do also as this answer described.  Using Windows Server 2012; sounds like it applies to anything newer than win7.

Comment: Many thanks, worked for me on Win 7 64bit. I waited 5 years before moving to 64bit and I can see it is still going to take longer to develop in.. /rant off

Comment: Thank you! Nothing I tried was helping until THIS. Using Windows 8.

Comment: Works perfect on Windows 8.1 preview

Comment: This worked for Windows 8.1 pro. I'm gonna name my son after you. Thank you very much!

Comment: Win 8.1 64 confirmed. Can just click Back, then Next

Answer (score 7):

I fixed this issue follow these steps:

1. right click my computer->properties->advanced system settings->advanced tab->click environmental variable
2. under system variales press new to create and new system variable
3. give it name JAVA_HOME and give url to folder where java is installed

   e.g `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05`
   and then re-run sdk

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you had to do, was to set the path to the jdk source folder.

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\"

That worked for me having that error.

Answer (score 0):

@hasan-veli-soyalan I tried your solution, but my `c:\windows\system\java.exe` not exist in my case, I'm using Windows 8 pro 64bit, instead, i found `c:\windows\system32\java.exe` and i changed it as you described, it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

you just need delete the "java.exe" of "C:\windows\System32\", and reset the java environment(JAVA_HOME,CLASSPATH,PATH), then you will successful pass this step.

By the way , i am under Windows7 X64

Answer (score 0):

This error often occur if not always because android sdk does not recognise "java" in sub-folder "System32" as "java.exe". Simply rename it to "java.exe".  Sub-folder "System32" is found in Local Disk(C:)>>Windows. Scroll down to find "java" in sub-folder "System32".

This should work provided "Java jdk" is properly installed on your system. Goodluck!

Answer (score -1):

I had faced the same error while installing android, try system restore and then reinstall jre and jdk

Comment: I have resolved the problem, in the environment variables, I was adding the path to my java installation on the upper part which is the user variable. when I added the path to the lower part which is the system variables, the android sdk installation recognised the file. I am sure this might help some other person. This is all about care and attention to details.

Answer (score -2):

To install Android and work with Android Studio on your first app, here are the step by step instructions:

- Step 1: Download Android Studio
- Step 2: Install Android Studio Step
- Step 3: Start a new project
- Step 4: Create new AVD
- Step 5: Open AVD Manager
- Step 6: Launch Emulator
- Step 7: Run Project

Whereas while [installing Android](https://studyopedia.com/android/setup-android-environment/), you need to also set Environment variables.

To set Environment Variables, the same steps are followed while [installing Java](https://studyopedia.com/java/install-java-on-windows/) to set JDK.

Go to Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings > Advanced tab > Environment Variables.

Under System Variable, click Path, then New and add the JDK path.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Thank you, @Machavity! I have added more information.