# Android Eclipse plug in Error?

Tags: android

when I plug in android to Eclipse I got an error.

I downloaded the windows installer , when I try to run the installer it shows

**Error : failed to find java version for "C:\windows\system32\java.exe' The system cannot find the file specified.**

What can I do for this error.

Comment: are you having jdk installed in your pc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check whether you have already installed Java in your machine. You can download latest version from [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-se-jdk-7-download-432154.html).

Please check [this](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html) for requirements to develop Andriod app.

Otherwise,it probably because of wrong configurations.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339679/android-installation-issues) will also help you too.

Good Luck !