# Android SDK suddenly stopped working

Tags: java, android, windows, sdk, 64-bit

After a couple of months with no Android development, I ran the SDK Manager yesterday, and upgraded from r16 to r18. After that upgrade, everything stopped working. I downloaded a fresh copy of the SDK tools from Google. The Windows installer complains there's no Java installed (the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382178/android-sdk-installation-doesnt-find-jdk) , which used to work before, doesn't work).

I downloaded the ZIP file instead and put it in the right place. Running `SDK Manager.EXE` does nothing (it just returns immediately to the command prompt). Running tools\android.bat displays an error complaining "Failed to convert path to a short DOS path: c:\windows\system32\java.exe", and then suggests I install Java.

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit, with Java 1.7 (64 bit) properly installed (Eclipse runs well, the Android tools r16 ran very well until yesterday). c:\windows\system32\java.exe exists and works as it should.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: I found an old r16 setup around. I installed it and everything went back to normal.

Comment: I had a similar problem, did you try manually changing the registry? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4739559/1267661

Comment: I just did, it didn't change anything.

Comment: I also had trouble with the JDK PATH variable once: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I put this one aside for a while, but now I had to get it back running. I didn't want to install a 32-bit Java VM alongside the 64 bit one I have.

I found the culprit. in `android_sdk\tools\lib` there's a batch-file called `find_java.bat`. It calls `find_java.exe -s` to find a list of potential Java locations. Running the exe file like this returns the error I've been seeing:

```
Failed to convert path to short DOS path: c:\windows\system32\java.exe
```

-s stands for short. Running it without the -s causes find_java.exe to work, causing find_java.bat to work, causing everything else to work. So the fix was to edit find_java.bat, and remove the -s .

I honestly don't know what Google is thinking.

Comment: Great, I had the same problem. Maybe Google is thinking no one should use windows...

Answer (score 3):

My fix was to remove /bin from my JAVA_HOME, as in C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin  --> C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\

I'm running 64bit java on W7.

This google issue was helpful:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23648

Answer (score 2):

This is just a guess, but I advise you to install JDK 6. It is said in the [SDK requirements](http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html) that you have to use it. I remember that I installed JDK 7 and I had some kind of trouble with it too.

Also it is safer to use the 32-bit version.

Comment: Up until yesterday I had no trouble with JDK 7 and 64-bit. Why did it break? I really don't want two Java platforms installed unless I absolutely have to.

Comment: @zmbq Obviously, they rely on some specific behavior of JDK 6 or don't wish to test their code against JDK 7 for some reason. You got lucky everything worked fine, but unfortunately this is not always the case. By the way, I remembered what was exactly the problem with JDK 7: I couldn't sign my APKs.

Comment: OK, I'll try downgrading to JDK 6 (I don't need JDK 7's additional features).

Comment: Downgrading to JDK 6 (64-bit version) did not work - the error is exactly the same.

Comment: @zmbq As I said, it is better to try the 32-bit version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also update the Eclipse plugins via Help > Install New Software.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix same like problem by adding the jdk path  to PATH variable in environment variables.