# JDK for android app development

Tags: java, android

Im trying to get started with app development. Isnt this the corrent JDK if i want to use eclipse + android plugin?

Java SE Development Kit 7u5: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1637583.html

When i try to install the android SDK tools it tells me that i dont have the correct JDK installed.

And yes, ive tried this already: [Android SDK installation doesn't find JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382178/android-sdk-installation-doesnt-find-jdk)

Thanks

Comment: Did you try reading the requirements for the Java JDK version at the Android SDK site? Seems like that would be a better (and quicker) place to find the answer.

Comment: Happened to me each time I've installed it on Win 7 (x86 and x64). 
If you've correctly set your JAVA_HOME env var, then when it says it cannot find any JDK, press back and then next again. I know... :)

Comment: @marceln Ok, where do i set the variable?

Comment: Here's a step-by-step post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7. If you haven't set it yet, then it may very well be the cause of your problems.

Comment: @marceln Allright, thanks for the link

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Java 7 is not officially supported by the Android SDK at this time. Please use the latest version of the Java 6 JDK.

**UPDATE**: Java 7 is now supported.

Comment: JDK7 can be installed, and then the SDK will just use the level 6 API.I'm running it like that.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I would appreciate it if you can update your answer. It's not entirely correct in it's current form. Thanks.

Comment: I solved it by installing the 32 bit version, based on a comment in the thread that i linked. Please update this answer. Its working with JDK7 as marceln said

Comment: @marceln: Until such time as [the official system requirements](http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html) say otherwise, Java 7 is not officially supported, and I have had multiple people report problems using Java 7 with the Android SDK. I have adjusted my answer to reflect the "officially supported" nuance. If you can get it to work and want to run that way, more power to you.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I got serious problem with jdk7, first of all ADT Bundle is not working with it since eclipse.ini parameters are not customized for jdk7. meanwhile after some quick fixes, eclipse is crashing repeatedly. However I always adore you for your books and detailed answers :)

Comment: @VSB: FWIW, I have been using JDK 7 for the past few months with Eclipse 3.8.1 on Ubuntu 13.04/13.10, with no issues (other than the typical sorts of Eclipse instabilities that I have had for years). And Xav indicated that Java 7 is officially supported, though I forget if the Web site has been updated to that end. And thanks for the kind words!

Comment: @CommonsWare: since i'm using Windows, we may have different experiences. Before JDK7 everthing with eclipse was fine:) I'm just trying to install JDK6u38 to rollback to good old days! my current eclipse is 4.2.1