# Android SDK install failed, can't find java version

Tags: android, sdk, java

i searched on google for this but did not find any answer ...
i installed the Java SE SDK ver 7 but could not continue....
this is the error capture : 
[image: This is the error]

Anybody can explain why ? :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382178/android-sdk-installation-doesnt-find-jdk i think this is the same issue

Comment: @AviKumarManku : i've try it all but failed... can you describe me about JAVA_HOME configuration place ?

Comment: http://wso2.org/project/wsas/java/1.1/docs/setting-java-home.html see this will help you

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the 64 bit version, uninstall and use the 32 bit.