# Trying to install android sdk, says it java sdk is not installed

Tags: android

I'm trying to install the android sdk.
But it keeps saying Java se development kit not installed, I installed it twice.

The next line says "Errror failed to find java version of 
c:\Windows\system32\java.exe, well the file is there.

Then it says:
If you believe you have installed the sdk, simply set a environment verbal java)home to point to it,
well I hava java home as
c:\java\jdk1.7.0_05

and it still gives the same error,
how do I get pass this?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382178/android-sdk-installation-doesnt-find-jdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android requires Java 1.5 or 1.6.  It will not work properly with 1.7.

So downloand and install the 1.6 JDK and I believe your issue will go away.

Comment: Hi,I tried to uninstall the 1.7 version, then the 1.6 version, still did not work, any idears??????

Comment: Did you change the home path to point to the 1.5/1.6 install?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem before. Press Back and then Next, things will be OK.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it doesn't work without **32 bit** JDK. Just install itfirst.

Comment: Hi,I install it did not work, I also tried to unstill the old version I have then install the 32 bit version, still did not work any idear???