# Android SDK r20 - Windows 7 - Install Java JDK Not Found

Tags: java, android

[Android SDK installation doesn't find JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382178/android-sdk-installation-doesnt-find-jdk) is not the same release as this, and the solution "back" then "next" doesn't work.

I have tried installing various versions of Java and nothing seems to be working. I've been trying to get this installed for the last 3 days. Solutions I have tried that do NOT work:

- Pushing the back button then the next button.
- Adding an Environment Variable for JAVA_HOME that points to the System32 path and the actual java install directory.
- Installing various versions of Java. (Java 6 and Java 7)

The install file is called `installer_r20.0.3-windows` and is the current exe available at http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

[image: Error Message]
[image: java.exe]

Comment: what happens when you fire `javac` at your command prompt ?

Comment: It gave an error. After that, I added `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_34\bin` to the "Path" env var and it now works in command prompt, but the installer still doesn't work.

Comment: can you print the path variable's value ?

Comment: I should mention that this is a brand new installation of Windows 7 on a brand new PC. (Installed 3 days ago) `C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_34\bin`

Comment: ok, as it is windows system , i suggest you to restart your pc once.

Comment: I've restarted just about every time I've tried something, but I did it again just now and still nothing.

Comment: ok, what is the value of your `JAVA_HOME` ?

Comment: Currently: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_34\bin Although I have tried C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_34\bin\java.exe

Comment: oh ok, change it to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_34`  , you do not nee to add bin folder in the JAVA_HOME Path.

Comment: Post your answer as a solution please.

Comment: Yes, please post as answer so I can mark it correct. :)

Comment: Thanks, not sure why they had to make it so hard to install, heh.

Comment: I believe that, from the path, it automatically search for javac.exe and other .exe files, so you dont need to add full the path till .exe file, otherwise it may omit the upper folder's other .exe file to get execute( this is only my belief ).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, looking at to your JAVA_HOME path which is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_34\bin` I suggest you to change it as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_34\`. There is no need to add bin folder's path in the JAVA_HOME Path.

Comment: Tried all variations of this, but it doesn't work. I have JDK 1.7.0_02.

Comment: do you have jre folder in that JDK folder ?

Answer (score 5):

On my Win7 Ultimate 64 bits/ i need multiple things

1. Set SystemEnvironment Variable JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07
2. Add the same value to SystemEnvironment Variable PATH, but make sure to put it before system32 path
   PATH = C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_07;C:\Windows\system32; ....... (...  = current value)
3. and most important , i guessed. Rename c:\windows\system32\java.exe -> c:\windows\system32\java.exe.old
4. Restart the installer (my case = installer_r20.0.3-windows.exe )

Voila!

This might help safe other's time

Comment: what's the point of renaming java.exe to java.exe.old? this method worked but I can't understand the reason behind renaming...

Comment: @saji159 I would guess that renaming it does two things: 1) It makes the java.exe not get called first when "java" is called and it preserves the backup / old java.exe.

Answer (score 2):

Setting JAVA_HOME environment variable in System variable to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\` did solve my problem.

A couple of points to note.

1. No need to specify bin or jre folder name.
2. You will need to cancel and restart the Android SDK installation. Previous/Next may not work.
3. I just copied the folder name from Windows explorer address bar. No need to replace the `\` with `/`.