# jdk not found in windows 7

Tags: android, sdk, java, android-sdk-2.3

I have installed `jdk-7u7-windows-x64` on my windows 7 (64 bit) machine, but when I try to install to  `installer_r20.0.3-windows` gives me the following error

> Java SE Development Kit not found. Failed to find Java version on "C:\Windows\system32\java.exe". The system cannot find the file specified

I have set the system variable `JAVA_HOME` to

> %Program Files%\Java\jre7\bin

but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `installer_r20.0.3-windows` is the installer for the Android SDK;

From the System requirements of the Android SDK ([here, click System Requirements](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html))

```
JDK 6 (JRE alone is not sufficient)
```

You've installed JDK7 which is not listed as working. I'd recommend you install a 32 bit JDK6 since it's a known working configuration. 64-bit *should* work, but [the installer is known to have had some issues with that version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382178/android-sdk-installation-doesnt-find-jdk).

Answer (score 2):

You set jre path not jdk path. After installing JDK, the default path is something similar to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.07`. Add this to path as `JAVA_HOME` and then test the installation with cmd `javac -version` in command line.

Answer (score 1):

i solved problem . first delete c:\windows\system32\java.exe . when deleted re install JDK and run installer_r22.0.1-windows ( ur version ) .

Answer (score -1):

Remove or rename java.exe in this path
windows/system32/java.exe
then follow SDK installation with a previous - next button
after finish installation return java.exe as what it be

Comment: This just sounds wrong. Could you clarify why you think this should work and perhaps refer to an authoritative source?