# Getting Android SDK installation to find JDK dropped javaw.exe out of Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, windows-8, path

After using this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/10025861/2654421 to get the Android SDK installer to find java with `PATH` to `C:/Windows/system32/java.exe` on Windows8 x64, I can no longer open Eclipse because it can't find a javaw.exe in the PATH. I'm pretty sure I've fixed this by dropping java.exe from `PATH` to just `C:/Windows/system32/`, but I haven't been able to check that Android SDK can still find java because it's currently installing the SDKs. Can anyone tell me if I've broken something else now?

Comment: You are supposed to set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable so that eclipse/android sdk can find your java install. If you want to be able to call jdk binaries from cmd you should append `;<path to JDK/bin>` to your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks @Robadob. Setting `JAVA_HOME` doesn't seem to do anything for Eclipse's ability to find java, but I've added the jre/bin to `PATH`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FAQ section [Find the JVM](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse?#Find_the_JVM) could be of interest:

> **Eclipse DOES NOT consult the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable**.
>
> To explicitly specify a JVM of your choice, you can use the `-vm` command line argument:

```
eclipse -vm c:\jre\bin\javaw.exe              ''start Java by executing the specified java executable
eclipse -vm c:\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll         ''start Java by loading the jvm in the eclipse process
```

See the launcher page for more details on specifying a JVM.
eclipse.ini

> The most recommended way to specify a JVM for Eclipse to run in is to put startup configuration into the **`eclipse.ini`** file in the same folder as the Eclipse executable (`eclipse.exe` on Windows).
> The Eclipse program launcher will read arguments from either the command-line or the configuration file named `eclipse.ini`.
> To specify a JVM using configuration file, include the **`-vm`** argument in `eclipse.ini`, for example:

```
-vm
c:/jre/bin/javaw.exe
```