# Android SDK cannot find JDK

Tags: java, android, java-7

all, I am using Windows 8.1 pro x64. I have installed JDK 7 and tried to install Android SDK, but the installation keeps telling me that the JDK was not found. I have already set the `JAVA_HOME` and `Path` variable to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45. It still doesn't work, so how do I fix the issue?

cheers

Comment: There's a known issue with the installer.  It may be fixed, but when you're installing the Android SDK, press back and then forward when you get to the "find the JDK" step.  (Trust me, I'm not crazy)

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 is right. Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382178/android-sdk-installation-doesnt-find-jdk

Comment: Hi, I did have tried the 'back and forth' method multiple times, but with no luck, so I am confused. The last time, I closed the installation and started again, it works. Strange...

Comment: Welcome to Android development!

Comment: Doesn't PATH need to be set to the **Bin** subdirectory of the Java install path?  e.g. PATH=%PATH%;c:\program files\jdk1.7.0_45\bin

Answer (score 2):

Same issue, after immense frustration and blind dead end suggestions I managed to install it on my friends windows 7 machine using the following in the environment variables.

**CLASSPATH**            %HOME_JAVA%\jre\lib

**ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK**   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40

**JAVA_HOME**            C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40

**JRE_HOME**             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40

**JDK_HOME**             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40

Plus: removed old paths and links to Java, removed old Registry paths

However I need to install it on my windows 7 machine and windows Vista and I have had no luck.

Additionally I have tried placing a "\" at the end of the paths,  the back and forward clicking etc, it all fails. I have changed to a 32bit version of Java JDK.

The major issue I have is that all the answers seem to be hacks and guessing, not just in this forum, but all the forums. No one really knows the issue. I'd pay someone to tell me exactly step by step what to do ,and why it will work, and have it succeed more importantly.

The odd part is that Google have known about this for years and have zero attempt to fix, even their dialogue box to browse to the Java path fails to work.

I was most hopeful about this **ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK** as a new environment variable, but it too fails to work.

NOTE:  Google suggest you open up a command dos window and use this commend

**javac -version**

and thats a great suggestion, its lets you know that your Java JDK is properly installed, you may need to reboot as some Java commands are memory resident.

I hope what I posted can help someone. I am going back to looking for solutions, any help will be appreciated.