# Android SDK Manager not open in eclipse

Tags: android

I have window7 (64bit) and java7 (64 bit) installed .

I downloaded [android sdk bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=sk).

After extracting the zip, i opened eclipse and tried to open SDK Manager from

"Windows->Android SDK Manager".

But SDK Manager does not open and shows the following error in the console.

```
[2014-05-14 10:25:47 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] '"E:\ADT-BU~1\sdk\tools\lib\\find_java.exe" -s' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[2014-05-14 10:25:47 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] operable program or batch file.
```

I have added 
[System variables](http://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

1)When I execute find_java.bat for android sdk it returns

[image: path of jdk]

[image: Excution of android.bat]

2)When i run android.bat from CMD[image: Excution of android.bat]

3)When i run the command "Where java" it returns the path [image: Run command " Where java" it return to path]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and execute
the command "where java" after navigating to the sdk folder in command prompt?

Try resetting the JAVA_HOME variable

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588548/help-jdk-not-detected-problem-during-android-sdk-tools-setup/6051580#6051580

or check this out

[Android SDK installation doesn't find JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382178/android-sdk-installation-doesnt-find-jdk)

Comment: After execute "where java" command returns to location of java.please check I had update question