# Android Studio bundle Error JDK

Tags: android, android-studio

I wanna install android studio bundle,but i get this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GJza.jpg)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382178/android-sdk-installation-doesnt-find-jdk

Answer (score 0):

Install JDK v7 or 7 up version.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download jdk 1.8+

https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html