# Can't locate JDK on Windows 7

Tags: windows, eclipse, adt, java

I believe similar questions have been asked before, but none of them matches mine perfectly. So I'm posting this one.

I'm using the Eclipse IDE in ADT bundle. Currently I'm doing some basic Java programming. Prior to this, I had downloaded and installed JDK from Orcale. The problem occurred when trying to set up Javadoc, as it needed the path to javac. Now, if I try `where java`, I get `C:\Windows\System32\java.exe`. If I try `where javac`, I get `not found error`. To complicate matters even further, `echo %PATH%` gives (I've added newlines for clarity):

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\Common Files\GTK\2.0\bin;C:\Python32;C:\Program Files\Calibre2\
```

But guess what, there's no folder by the name of jdk1.7.0_03 in the Program Files\Java directory! All I have is the "jre" folder.

I'm thoroughly confused. Where is the javac program? Where was the JDK installed? Am I missing something important here? Please help!

Comment: I'd expected it to be normally installed in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_xx` (where xx is the update), unless you changed it's default installation location...

Comment: But there's only jre, and yet I'm able to build projects! I don't at all remember changing installation location, but then there's no entry in PATH and I can build core Java projects. :(

Comment: Are you sure you installed the JDK and not the JRE?  Try going to the "Programs and Features" (in the Control Panel) and uninstall the JRE and JDK and reinstall it.

Comment: I have "Java 7 Update 21" listed in Control Panel. In fact, there's no JRE listed there. "Java 7 Update 21" is the only entry with J. Does that mean I never installed JRE? If so, where is this JDK installed?

Comment: Is there anything under C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin?

Comment: As I said in my post, there's only one folder inside Program Files\Java, and that is "jre". I'm beginning to wonder if the JDK is actually installed. By the way, can Eclipse build Java projects even with the JRE? How can I really test the presence of JDK?

Comment: Try searching for `javac.exe` on your harddisk

Comment: No javac.exe. I get a javacpl.exe located in C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First [download the jdk from oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk6u37-downloads-1859587.html). During the installation, you should find a path to install your jdk, for example, `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin`. Then you should set up the environment variable for your jdk in Control panel -> System -> Advanced -> Environment Variables. The detail can be found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1672536/1365960).

Answer (score 0):

The javac file is usually in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin\javac

If you can't find it in that path, maybe the one that you installed is not jdk or maybe it is the wrong jdk. You don't need to install JRE, the JDK package has already contained JRE in it.
If you can't find javac in that path, maybe you installed the wrong java executable. Try to uninstall Java and install it again using the newest update.
Don't forget to set the CLASSPATH.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I'd much rather like to learn what's going on in my system right now. There's no JDK to be found, and yet I'm able to build projects. How's that possible?

Comment: Okay, I may have found the answer on another forum. It says that Eclipse has a built-in compiler of its own, which lets you work only if you have JRE installed. How do I close this post? :)