# undefined reference to 'WinMain@16' (C++)

Tags: c++

My question is not answered by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) because I made a very different type of mistake, I now know.  The project was incorrectly set up.  It needed to be a console application for my purposes which it was not.

I am a new C++ programmer. I'm using Code::Blocks and working on Windows, and every time I try to add a class to my project, it begins returning this same error, even though it appears as if I'm telling my project where to build to (which was the solution suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284720/undefined-reference-c)).

Here is my attempted code:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Monster.h

```
#ifndef MONSTER_H
#define MONSTER_H


class Monster
{
    public:
        Monster();
        virtual ~Monster();
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // MONSTER_H
```

Monster.cpp

```
#include "Monster.h"

Monster::Monster()
{
    //ctor
}

Monster::~Monster()
{
    //dtor
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: New programmer.  Checked that answer, too complex for my level of understanding.  (Though if you specified the part I was supposed to look at...)

Comment: possible duplicate of [undefined reference to \`WinMain@16'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259714/undefined-reference-to-winmain16)

Comment: possible duplicate of [undefined reference to WinMain@16 (codeblocks)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20020399/undefined-reference-to-winmain16-codeblocks)

Comment: Guilherme, both files appear to be linked, so the answer to that question doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: This answers http://stackoverflow.com/a/27084740/1518921 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/20020411/1518921 They seem much like the chosen answer for you. Remember it is not why the author of another question chose a response that it is the correct one for you, you can view other answers to the same question.

Comment: Yeah, I found other helpful answers too.  It seems in the end that Code::Blocks also has some issues that weren't resolving on my computer.  Trying a different compiler now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the project is configured as a Windows application rather than a console application.

Since you are using int main it will not know where to start.

You can set the entry point to int main function in the Code::Blocks additional linker options by adding '/entry:mainCRTStartup', or just as easily create a new console application workspace.

Comment: This appears to have worked in the short term!  I would swear on everything I know that I clicked console app, but the proof is in the pudding.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Okay, so more info...the error appears after I try adding a member function to the Monster class even if I started the project as a console application.

Comment: Note that the `/entry:` option is for Microsoft's linker, while in Code::Blocks one is most likely using g++ (and ld for linker).

Comment: From personal experience, I know that CodeBlocks (with GCC) accepts a regular `main` function with a Windows subsystem.