# Cannot start Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

After downloading a plugin, the Jenkins server cannot be accessed. I am using windows 7.
I tried to start windows Jenkins service manually, but I get the following message:

> "Windows could not start the Jenkins service on Local COmputer. Error
>   1067: The process terminated unexpectedly"

I also tried to run the jenkins.exe from the installation directory, but with no success.
In the error logs I see the following:

```
INFO: Obtained the updated data file for hudson.tasks.Maven.MavenInstaller
Ιουν 06, 2014 11:31:46 ΠΜ hudson.model.DownloadService$Downloadable doPostBack
INFO: Obtained the updated data file for hudson.tools.JDKInstaller
Ιουν 06, 2014 11:32:18 ΠΜ hudson.model.UpdateCenter doSafeRestart
INFO: Scheduling Jenkins reboot
Ιουν 06, 2014 11:33:00 ΠΜ hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob run
INFO: Starting the installation of FTP-Publisher Plugin on behalf of anonymous
Ιουν 06, 2014 11:33:15 ΠΜ hudson.model.UpdateCenter doRestart
INFO: Scheduling the core downgrade
Ιουν 06, 2014 11:33:25 ΠΜ hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration download
INFO: Downloading FTP-Publisher Plugin
Ιουν 06, 2014 11:33:26 ΠΜ hudson.model.UpdateCenter$HudsonDowngradeJob run
INFO: Starting the downgrade of jenkins.war on behalf of anonymous
Ιουν 06, 2014 11:33:26 ΠΜ jenkins.model.Jenkins$24 run
INFO: Restart in 10 seconds
Ιουν 06, 2014 11:33:26 ΠΜ hudson.model.UpdateCenter$HudsonDowngradeJob run
INFO: Downgrading successful: jenkins.war
Ιουν 06, 2014 11:33:36 ΠΜ jenkins.model.Jenkins$24 run
SEVERE: Restarting VM as requested by anonymous
Error: Unable to access jarfile D:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jenkins.war
Error: Unable to access jarfile D:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jenkins.war
Error: Unable to access jarfile D:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jenkins.war
```

Can anyone help? We are at release point, and I have nowhere to run my tests..

Comment: obvious question but is the path at the bottom relating the the jenkin.war accurate, do you have permissions and is it available?

Comment: First try to launch it using command line as user. If start without errors it's a problem related with user permissions.

Comment: I tried `D:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins>java -jar jenkins.war
Error: Unable to access jarfile jenkins.war` Is there a way to reinstall Jenkins without losing configuration?

Comment: I just saw that jenkins.war file is missing from the directory

Comment: you can copy the full directory jenkins/jobs to save configuration of every jobs.
However, you will have to reinstall all plugins and perform again main conf.

Comment: In my case I had to get rid of the new jenkins.war file and replace it with jenkins.war.bak

Answer (score 16):

Rather than guess which answer might be appropriate, you can check the `jenkins.err.log` file in the installation directory.

In my case, Jenkins complained about an unsupported JRE after an update. The fix was to download the required JRE, and tell `jenkins.exe` to use it by configuring the path in the `jenkins.xml` file.

Comment: Looking into logs immediately pinpointed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: In my case, the problem was that I was using the latest java 21 version which is not supported by Jenkins. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Check the `jenkins.xml` there should be something wrong in config. In my case changing `-Xmx2048m` to `-Xmx1024m` fixed. Since it is not supported the 2m heap size.

```
<arguments>-Xrs -Xmx1024m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=9090</arguments>
```

Comment: thank you very much, this is exactly what my issue was. but i dont undersand why wouldnt it support 2048?

Comment: Work for me as well. Thx

Answer (score 3):

thanks a lot for your comments.
Apparently the configuration was corrupted (missing war file) because a restart was made, while a plugin was being installed.
For my good luck, when i tried to uninstall jenkins (to install it again), i hit the repair button, and all the missing files and configuration was restored.
I have to give this point to windows OS :)

Answer (score 2):

Execute this by providing absolute path of the war file
java -jar

Answer (score 2):

1. Download jenkins.war at https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/war/
2. Put jenkins.war to `<jenkins root folder>`
3. Restart jenkins service

Comment: I tried this on linux ( /var/lib/jenkins ) but nothing happened

Answer (score 2):

I am added `--enable-future-java` flag after path to Jenkins.war and it successfully starts

Answer (score 1):

This error usually shows, when you don't have Java on your machine. Jenkins relay on Java.

Follow these steps to fix the issue:

```
sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk
systemctl enable jenkins
systemctl start jenkins
systemctl status jenkins
```

Hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Go and check with an environment variable in `_JAVA_OPTIONS` value, if the value is more then `-xmx256m` or `-xmx512m` then change it to one of these value.
it has worked for me

Comment: I have changed the xmx in order to increase memory for Jenkins and encountered the same problem, works fine after a revert, that was the right thing to do...thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed jenkins with msi (jenkins.msi), run the repair. That is run the file jenkins.msi again and choose to repair.

After the repair completes successfully it will start the service automatically.

Worked in my case! Had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I has a similar challenge today, on inspection of the Jenkins installation directory, I discovered a backup copy `jenkins.war.bak`. Therefore, I simply copied the file and renamed it to `jenkins.war`, and started `jenkins` and voila, everything worked normally.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look of **jenkins.err** text file from the **.jenkins** folder for the actual error.

For me it was related to **JVM**. i had to change value from **JAVA_OPTIONS**, previous it was jdk path so i changed it to value -Xmx512M.

Answer (score 0):

Open your c and users and PC name.
Delete the .jerkins folder
and
Restart the CMD Action again. IT will be work Dont worry.

Note :  Suppose if you are work in IT Company, there is some port specialities were  removed.  So  use the port number which is permit your office.
For Example :
java -jar jerkins.war --httpPort=3000

Enjoy...............

Answer (score 0):

I Installed JDK 8 instead of JDK 13, and, that is working well

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the java version should not be greater than 8 ([Why?](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/java/)). (If it is, download from [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/) and simply re-point your `$JAVA_HOME` to the current JRE.) (Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26640589/3375356)
[image]

Preferably install using WAR file instead of installing it as a Windows service as that would require that account that runs Jenkins to have permission to log in as a service.

- `cd` to the path where **jenkins.war** file is kept and run `java -jar jenkins.war`.

Or

- Change the JRE path, if installing using `jenkins.msi`
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue due to the older 1.8 version of custom JDK, but got it resolved by changing the java path in jenkins.xml
`<executable>update here\jdk-11.0.16.1_windows-x64_bin\jdk-11.0.16.1\bin\java.exe</executable>`