# android studio - with open this message apper

Tags: java, android, jvm

The environment variable JAVA_HOME (with the value of *c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20*) does not point to a valid JVM installation.

Someone can help me?

Comment: Add a slash at the end of the string like this `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\ ` , try. does it worked?

Comment: it show me that program is not recognize

Answer (score 0):

edit your environment variable JAVA_HOME to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin;` Restart your computer.

Comment: how can i do this? i really not understand in this thing

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation

Comment: enter to the computer proprieties, and add a new environment, JAVE_HOME, and where that me install of jdk, i copy, and add "bin;", after reset the comp and it is not working

Answer (score 0):

- Go to Environment variable.
- Go to User variable and check if there is JAVA_HOME variable.
- If yes please delete the JAVA_HOME variable for User variable
- Go to System variables.
- See if there is JAVA_HOME variable is added or not.
- If there no JAVA_HOME variable please add new system variable.
- Click on New and enter Variable Name = JAVA_HOME and Variable value = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20"
- And Save the settings.

This setting will solve the above problem.

Thanks