# i'm having a trouble for installing JDK during installation of android studio.....i'm facing below error

Tags: android

[I trying to browse JDK from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin but still showing me this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eo8kB.png)

Answer (score 1):

first of all used this version of JDK if you used for android studio

jdk-8u60-windows-x64/32 regarding your os,

jre-8u60-windows-x64

install both JDK & JRE and set ENVIREMENT_VARIABLE,

if you dont know how to set, you can find it [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation) here