# Can't we run main method inside enum?

Tags: java, enums, java-8, enumeration

I had seen a video where, `main()` can be run with in an `enum`.
I am trying to do the same but it's not working.

Here is my code

```
public enum EnumMain {                             
   ABC, XYZ;                                       
   public static void main(String[] args) {        
     System.out.print("MIAN");                     
   }                                               
}
```

**Output**
(The code compiles fine)
`Error: Could not find or load main class EnumMain`

I think this has something to do with the Java version, may be in Java 8, they are not allowing to run `main()` method from `enum` anymore.

**PS** I am compiling and running the file from windows command prompt.

**Note** If I change the `enum` to `class` then it runs fine (I don't have any classpath issues)

Comment: What's the package of your class and from which folder do you execute your program?

Comment: @dunni there is no package, I am just creating a .Java file and compiling, running it from command prompt.

Comment: What's the exact command which you use to execute it?

Comment: There is nothing special about enums and main method. Change your enum to regular class and you'll see you still can't run the main, because you have class path issues.

Comment: @Bohemian I can run the class if I change the enum to class, it's sad that you marked it as duplicate, without knowing the situation rofl

Comment: @SoumitriPattnaik I can run your code OK. The problem your have has nothing to do with it being an enum.

Comment: See… [it works](http://ideone.com/9BOrQA).

Comment: @Holger yes, but in my machine it does not, I can run main in a class, I don't know what is the problem

Comment: We don’t have any information about your machine except what you have written in your question (in other words, nothing). It’s supposed to work, it does work on our machines, it works in Java 7 and Java 8, so whatever your problem is, it’s not described in your question…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run main within enum.

```
public enum TestEnumMain{
    val1, val2;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Problem would be with you your path variables. Make sure they are configured right. Refer [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation) for setting path variables propertly.

Comment: If I had classpath problem, then I could not run any Java class, but I can, so it's not about classpath.

Comment: Can you include the exact command you were trying with, your path variable value and path where your enum file is ?

Comment: `echo %JAVA_HOME%`  returns `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45`

And I can see it in my `PATH` as well

Answer (score 0):

No, I have run your code on `Java 8` and it is perfect. It runs to give output `MIAN`. I think the problem lies in `classpath` or in your `IDE`. You might try after cleaning the project.

Comment: What is your exact java version, mine is "1.8.0_66"

You can check that by, typing "java -version" in your command prompt.\

Comment: I am running the file using notepad and cmd prompt

Comment: My Java version is: `java version "1.8.0_45"`

Comment: @SoumitriPattnaik Even I have also run it on command prompt. It's OK. Please use `-cp .` if your `java` does not find `main` class.

Comment: @SoumitriPattnaik Does this program work on your system?

Comment: if I change the `enum` to `class` and remove the enum constants, then it runs perfectly fine. If I make it `enum`, then only it's showing the error.