# Migrating to Google Cloud Endpoints Framework for Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an existing multi-module Gradle-based Google App Engine (GAE) project, which was initially based from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-sample-java.

The project has Cloud Endpoints for App Engine, and I'm migrating it to **Cloud Endpoints Framework** ("cloud endpoints version 2"). I followed https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/required_files, which means I changed these:

**build.gradle**

```
+       compile 'com.google.endpoints:endpoints-framework-auth:1.0.0-beta.10'
+       compile 'com.google.endpoints:endpoints-management-control-appengine:1.0.0-beta.10'
```

**appengine-web.xml**

```
+       <env-variables>
+               <env-var name="ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_NAME" value="myproject.appspot.com" />
+       </env-variables>
```

**web.xml**

```
+       <!-- Endpoints service config from service management -->
+       <filter>
+               <filter-name>endpoints-api-configuration</filter-name>
+               <filter-class>com.google.api.control.ServiceManagementConfigFilter</filter-class>
+       </filter>
+       <filter-mapping>
+               <filter-name>endpoints-api-configuration</filter-name>
+               <servlet-name>api</servlet-name>
+       </filter-mapping>
+
+       <!-- Endpoints logging and monitoring -->
+       <filter>
+               <filter-name>endpoints-api-controller</filter-name>
+               <filter-class>com.google.api.control.extensions.appengine.GoogleAppEngineControlFilter</filter-class>
+               <init-param>
+                       <param-name>endpoints.projectId</param-name>
+                       <param-value>myproject</param-value>
+               </init-param>
+               <init-param>
+                       <param-name>endpoints.serviceName</param-name>
+                       <param-value>myproject.appspot.com</param-value>
+               </init-param>
+       </filter>
+       <filter-mapping>
+               <filter-name>endpoints-api-controller</filter-name>
+               <servlet-name>api</servlet-name>
+       </filter-mapping>
```

(I've done the part in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/migrating which I will not discuss here)

But I encounter this error when trying to run it using "gradle appengineRun":

```
    Oct 24, 2016 8:53:12 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
    INFO: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value '/Users/username/.gradle/appengine-sdk/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.42/config/sdk/logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from '/Users/username/Documents/code/myproject/web/ear/build/exploded-app/default-1.0/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml'
    Oct 24, 2016 8:53:12 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl <init>
    INFO: Ignoring application.xml context-root element, for details see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#config
    com.google.appengine.tools.development.EnvironmentVariableChecker$IncorrectEnvironmentVariableException: One or more environment variables have been configured in appengine-web.xml that have missing or different values in your local environment. We recommend you use system properties instead, but if you are interacting with legacy code that requires specific environment variables to have specific values, please set these environment variables in your environment before running.
    [Mismatch environmentVariableName=ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_NAME environmentVariableValue=null appEngineWebXmlValue=myproject.appspot.com appEngineWebXmlFile=/Users/username/Documents/code/myproject/web/ear/build/exploded-app/default-1.0/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml]
            at com.google.appengine.tools.development.EnvironmentVariableChecker.check(EnvironmentVariableChecker.java:75)
            at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.checkEnvironmentVariables(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:240)
            at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.access$000(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:32)
            at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager$EarModuleConfigurationHandle.checkEnvironmentVariables(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:486)
            at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.connectContainer(JettyContainerService.java:213)
            at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.createConnection(AbstractContainerService.java:269)
            at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractInstanceHolder.createConnection(AbstractInstanceHolder.java:37)
            at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.createConnection(AbstractModule.java:73)
            at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.createConnections(Modules.java:99)
            at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:239)
            at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:45)
            at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:217)
            at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:215)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:215)
            at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:277)
            at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
            at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:225)
            at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:216)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I try to execute the same command in my sample application and the error was the same. But it is weird, because there is no error when I deployed the application to google cloud. The cloud is working fine. I think it can be a bug in a local development server. Try to deploy it into the cloud, just to make sure if everythink in your code is ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added an enviroment variable with:

```
key = ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_NAME 
value = myproject.appspot.com
```

([here how to add an enviroment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1672536/3309466))

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appref) are the google docs that explain the meaning of this tag:

> Optional. The appengine-web.xml file can define environment variables
>   that are set when the application is running.
>
> To avoid conflicts with your local environment, the
>   development server does not set environment variables based on this
>   file, and requires that the local environment have these variables
>   already set to matching values.