# How to solve Apache jmeter installing error?

Tags: java, jmeter, findstr

I am truing jmeter latest version in windows 7 ultimate version 6.1.7601 .
I have java 1.7.9.10, I added jdk to my system path, and added jre 7 also.
[please click to see the error]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWTky.png

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you don't have JRE installed (Java Runtime Environment). Dowload installer from Oracle, install it and add folder with java.exe to PATH environment variable (see second answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation)

Comment: did you try setting **JAVA_HOME** in the path?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add **bin** folder of your JDK or JRE to PATH so JMeter could find the existing Java installation. If you have just installed JRE - restart CMD process so it could pick up the relevant PATH entries.

Also make sure that `java -version` command reports you're sitting on JDK or JRE not earlier than 1.7

[image: JMeter Installation]

More information: [How to Get Started With JMeter: Part 1 - Installation & Test Plans](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-part-1-installation-test-plans)

Comment: same things I did what you have told.. but same error coming

Answer (score -1):

set **JAVA_HOME** environment variable.

> To install a release build, simply unzip the zip/tar file into the directory where you want JMeter to be installed. Provided that you have a JRE/JDK correctly installed and the JAVA_HOME environment variable set, there is nothing more for you to do.

Note: There can be problems (especially with client-server mode) if the directory path contains any spaces.

References:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6521412/2575259
2. http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#install