# Cannot build a project in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I am trying to import a project in Android Studio. This code supposedly works but I cannot seem to be able to build the project. This is the error that is produced when I am trying to build:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':openCVLibrary2410:compileReleaseJava'.
>
> > Cannot find System Java Compiler. Ensure that you have installed a JDK (not just a JRE) and configured your JAVA_HOME system variable to
> >     point to the according directory.

I have searched for a solution, but what I found was was either referring to eclipse or changing the jdk position for

```
File > other Settings > Default Project Structure
```

Which is not a valid solution for me because I checked my previous Android Studio Projects and all have the same position

This is the stacktrace:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task     ':openCVLibrary2410:compileReleaseJava'.
```

> mainProject Gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to      all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
     repositories {
         jcenter()
     }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}

 allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

> FaceRecognition Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "eu.upcom.recred.facerec"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 9
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
     compile files('libs/javacpp.jar')
     compile files('libs/javacv.jar')
     compile project(':openCVLibrary2410')
 }
```

> openCV2410  gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post your gradle file..because recently i used this library on my camera app

Comment: is you project and 'openCVLibrary2410' project in the same directory?

Comment: Yes it is in the same directory

Comment: Check your java compiler path.Like this select file---->Other settings--->Default project structure and see your java path is properly set or not...because your gradle is perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I was posting here the gradle files my eye caught something. I changed the build tools version from `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'` to `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'`and now it is building as it should

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, Here is problem on Java path.  You can check you have  set path of your java or JDK in system variable or not click [Environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation)

Also check your Java JDK version.

Also this link have all details of How to set path. 
I suggest to you can use this solution. It will be help to resolve your problem..