# Unable to deploy app on computer even using install4j to bundle .jre

Tags: java

After bundling .jre with install4j; during installation, it was dsplaying "no suitable jre on the computer, and it should be located". Infact, what is the main funtion of this install4j. Am tired. I thought it would use my own bundled jre i downloaded to be able to run the app on other computers. someone should help me please.

Answer (score 0):

With the limited info, I'm assuming it's your path variable. Try following this question:

[Environment variables for java installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation)