# Java Programming with Microsoft Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I downloaded language support for Java by Red Hat in Microsoft Visual Studio Code, 
[image]

but I got a problem as shown in the above picture.

So I tried to set my JDK path in the `settings.json` file in VSCode:

```
"java.home": "C:/ProgramFiles/Java/jdk1.8.0_111"
```

But the problem is still not solved.

Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you check if that folder really exists and you have JDK installed ?

Comment: yes, I already installed JDK so i can compile and run my java programm by cmd. ㅠㅠ

Answer (score 15):

You have to restart VS Code after entering the java.home variable in the settings file.

Alternatively, setting that variable isn't even required. You can remove it from your settings and VS Code will automatically check your user/system environment variables for JDK_HOME and JAVA_HOME.

See "Setting the JDK" at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java

For information on how to set the environment variables, see [Environment variables for java installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation)

Answer (score 5):

you should change the path to be like this:

```
"java.home":"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_111"
```

Comment: **Edit**: `java_home` to `java.home` and add space between `Program` and `Files`. Couldn't edit it because it is less than 6 characters.

Answer (score 3):

My Visual Studio Code is set to use the 32 bit version of JDK

A default java.exe is installed in your %SYSTEMROOT%\System32

Check java version from command line:

> java -version

You might need to add your version to **PATH**:

> set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin

And set your system **JAVA_HOME**:

> setx -m JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_111"

Restart cmd and try:

echo %JAVA_HOME%

Restart Visual Studio Code and be happy.

Use `set` instead of `setx` for local user.

Comment: Best answer here

Comment: perfect! follow as instructed, restart vscode and totally happy

Answer (score 2):

try to change path as follow:

```
"java.home":"C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_202"
```

**Make attention to the space in "Program Files" in the path**.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bash from VSCode, should use:

`export JAVA_HOME=/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_172`

You can use this in the terminal there.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to put the space in between Program and files like:

> java.home :- "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_111"

Answer (score 0):

In case this question is still open.

Try placing a space between the words, Program and Files, so it reads:

> "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131"