# Starting Java Language server stuck at 37% in Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have just installed the Visual Studio code and redhat.java (Language support for Java by RedHat). I have added a new folder to workspace which contains many project modules.
When I try to open a Java file from those folders, I see that the redhat.java extension starts and is stuck alwas at 37%.

I tried deleting the folder in the /workspaceStorage from the %appdata%\Code\User\workspaceStorage and restarted the system.
I have also tried reinstalling the extension.

But still, the problem persists.

P.S:  I have no other extensions apart from this extension. This is the first extension that I am trying to install.

Comment: 1) is JAVA_HOME set? per here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42340927/java-programming-with-microsoft-visual-studio-code 2) Other users have commented on Github for JLS  that gradle might be issue. Perhaps mention version of that too (gradle -v)

Comment: @JGFMK Yes, it is set.

Comment: Although you mentioned deleteting workspaceStorage didn't work for you it did work for me on ubuntu 18 / vscode 1.40 (~/Code/User/workspaceStorage).