# Error while checking the java version in command prompt

Tags: java, android

On my windows 7, 64 bit pc, I have installed java but while typing java -version in command prompt it shows java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.".and there is no java folder in program files even.The java version which i have installed is 8 and it is 64bits.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the environment variables. 
The answer can be found on this [SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26640589/7812927).

Answer (score 0):

You must install the latest version of JDK from here:

[Download JDK From Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html)

After Installing the latest version follow these steps :

[Setting Path in Java](http://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-set-path-in-java)

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: I can't find the path of the downloaded file as it is not visible in my program files. I am not able to find way out of it as i am too new to these technical things.

Comment: it is generally `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin` 
copy the above path and paste it inside environment variable path