# Unable to locate JDK

Tags: xamarin, java-6

i ve installed visual studio 2017 but its giving me jdk error for xamarin. I have browsed to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\JavaJDKV2,version=1.8.1,chip=x64 but its still giving me error unable to locate JDK. Please guide me through.

Answer (score 0):

[Environment variables for java installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation/1672536#1672536)

Add Java to your Environment variables as shown in the above post.

Make sure you already have Java installed on your computer:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html