# Changing the path of java file

Tags: java

How can I change the path of the file after downloading jdk in Windows and then changing the file path in settings.i have changed the path. It still in command prompt it's showing that no java file installed and I am not able to run any program.

Comment: Follow this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation

Comment: Did you open a new command prompt window after you changed the path?

Answer (score 0):

You could reinstall the JDK and change the path from there. There are so many updates anyway. People are probably going to hate on my answer but honestly it is the easiest and it will probably not be some big problem because of it. Just my opinion