# ENOENT error when starting serverless offline

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, serverless

When running `sls offline start` I'm getting:

```
$ sls offline start
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn java ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:367:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

My `serverless.yml` has:

```
plugins:
  - serverless-dynamodb-local
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-mocha-plugin
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run: `sls dynamodb install` first and then `sls offline start`. The error will not appear anymore.

Credits go to:
https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3247

Comment: The question is for general "how-to" fix for ENOENT-error, however, the answer is specific to dynamoDB.
Please edit the answer so it can also be helpful as a general use case

Answer (score 0):

If you've just installed java for the fist time you will probably have to restart your computer so that the java bin is properly in your $PATH

Comment: Why the downvote? This is exactly what needed to happen for me.
Windows server 2016.

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues with not having the JAVA at the first place on my machine and afterwards installing I haven't added that java in the environment variable ‍♂️. This might save someone's time as the Dynamodb is using the JAVA you need to have it in your machine.

So for installing JAVA [Head to Oracle Official](https://www.java.com/download/)

and afterwards for making java accessible into your terminal [checkout this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation)