# Do we need to set Windows environment variables for Java updates anymore?

Tags: java, windows

I've been setting Windows environment variables (like `JAVA_HOME`) every time I installed a Java update.  (As per [Environment variables for java installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation)).

However, I've recently noticed that Java updates add `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;` to the System Path (not the User Path). I removed `JAVA_HOME`, etc from my User Path, and `java -version` seems to work from any directory.

Does that mean that it is not necessary to do that simple but annoying task with each Java update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on what you are trying to do.

Generally, you don't need `JAVA_HOME` to run a Java app. Adding the location of the Java binaries to the `PATH` is sufficient for Windows to find and execute them.

However, e.g. a lot of application servers like [Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html) and build tools like [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/4.5/userguide/installation.html) will use `JAVA_HOME` to determine the location of your Java installation.

Answer (score 3):

Java itself does not use JAVA_HOME. Some third-party things like IDEs and Tomcat do. I've never set it as an environment variable in 20 years.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I don't even have JAVA_HOME set and I've been developing at this company for 6 years now (and other companies for 10+ years). To me, it tends to get in the way.  The last install sets the windows path which generally isn't what my IDE's, Tomcat, JBoss or SOAP-UI support so I just edit all their startup files to choose/set the JAVA_HOME they work with.