# Cannot start jmeter 3.3 with java 9

Tags: java, jmeter

For some reason, there is installed Java 8 and Java 9 on my computer with Win10Pro.

How to run JMeter?

As I found some info, there are two ways:

1) run last official JMeter 3.3 with Java 8 using system variable settings:
-- I set up sys.variables in windows system setup targeting to my Java 8 folder:

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin
```

-- and run jmeter.bat.

Result: JMeter was still starting in java9.

```
  "Error: Java version -- 9.0.1 -- is too low to run JMeter. Needs a Java version greater than or equal to 1.8.0 errorlevel=3"
```

2) to download last night build java9 compatible apache-JMeter-r1822461:
-- I set up system variable targeting to java9:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\bin
```

--I run the jmeter.bat:
Result:
nothing happened - just blink the cmd window and closed.

WHere the problem is, what to do?
thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 4):

Here's a message straight from [their website](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html):

> JMeter does not yet support JAVA 9, next JMeter version will support it, you can help and follow progress on this item in [Bug 61529](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61529).

Since you already have Java 8 installed on your machine, just run it with that.  Assuming `jmeter.bat` runs a `.jar` file, you can use the following as an example:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe" -jar jmeter.jar
```

If you want to use the `.bat` file, you'll have to change your environmental variables (PATH) to reflect Java 8: [Environment variables for java installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation)

**Edit 29 january 2018:**

- Note Java 9 will be supported in 4.0 which should be released in upcoming days.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least 3 options:

1. [Uninstall Java 9](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/uninstall_java.xml)

   - Click `Win + R`
   - Type `appwiz.cpl`
   - Find everything which contains `Java 9` and uninstall it
2. Amend your [PATH environment variable](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) so Java 8 executable comes first like:

   ```
   set PATH=c:\path\to\java8\bin;$PATH%
   ```

   You can insert the above line directly into *jmeter.bat* file or run it in a terminal prior to starting JMeter
3. Use one of the [nightly builds](http://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html), there is a chance the issue is resolved already

More information: [How to Get Started With JMeter: Part 1 - Installation & Test Plans](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-part-1-installation-test-plans)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JMeter 4 with which we don't see this issue anymore.

Otherwise, there's a fast but ugly way: comment the version check bloc in the launcher script(jmeter.sh, .bat) or specify the JDK in this launcher. Then it works with JDK 9 and 10.