# How to launch a cli Jar with double click?

Tags: java, jar

Is it possible to launch a cli java project by double click on the jar ?

Inside the jar, we have the manifest file with the main class well defined, but when we try to double click on jar it can't launch it and displays a generic error : `The java jar file could not be launched.`

We supposed that it's because it is only able to run this jar from the cli.

Is it right ?

PS : Sorry for my bad english, I'm french :)

Thanks !

Comment: `java -jar jarNameGoesHere` in command line this is how you run a jar. Not by double clicking on it.

Comment: I think it crashes for some "internal" reason... You could try to launch by command line with `java -jar yourjar.jar` to see possible errors.

Comment: ```java -jar yourjar.jar``` works. Any ideas ? @Alessandro

Comment: @StackFlowed I'm not in the cli when I double click but in the finder of course. So it's impossible without ```java -jar ...``` ?

Comment: You can convert your `.jar` file to `.exe` by using `Launch4j` program. And then it will work with double click.

Comment: Can you download a runnable jar from somewhere and see if that launches by double clicking? That'll tell you whether the issue is with your jar or your OS configuration. Although if it launches by `java -jar Foo.jar` it should work with double clicking. @StackFlowed have you never launched a jar file by double clicking?

Comment: @Kayaman No I haven't tried it yet ! ...

Comment: @EJusius that would be useless, and not just because he's on Mac OS.

Comment: @Kayaman sorry, I didn't notice that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the jar-file includes some sort of implementation of `Runtime` that runs the system's terminal or command prompt, it won't open a terminal/prompt window when double clicking it (if some sort of GUI-implementation have been made with e.g. Swing, it will however launch the GUI). However, you can create a separate file, which will launch the jar-file.

As it seems you're on Mac, you can just create a `.command`-file. If you just need to execute your `.jar`-file, create a file with the following content:

```
#! /bin/bash
java -jar /path/to/file.jar
```

Name it something you remember, but don't forget to add `.command` at the end.

**For Linux**, use `.sh` extension, with the same content.

For Mac and Linux, you might have issues with executing the files because of lacking the permissions, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) for changing permissions on files.

**For windows**, use `.bat` extension. Exchange the slashes with backslashes when defining the path, and omit the `#! /bin/bash`-line. You'll also have to add Java to your environment variables, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation).