# 'jshell' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: java, jshell, java-10

I am using the '`jshell` command in my machine it is not recognised. But java command is working fine. is there any environment setup for `jshell` in jdk 10

```
C:\Users\Kannan
λ jshell
'jshell' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Kannan
λ java -version
java version "10" 2018-03-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10+46)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10+46, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. check if jshell is installed with your Java environment.  `ls [JAVA-INSTALLEDPATH]/bin`
2. if jshell does not exist download appropriate JDK
3. if jshell is present append path in your environment profile or use full path.

Comment: On Windows, `ls` only works in Power Shell, not in the command prompt.

Comment: Thanks @Dwight J. Browne I have check JAVA_HOME environment and It was pointing to jdk8 path. I don't know why java version still showing java 10 . Any way issue is fixed

Answer (score 8):

`jshell` is a part of JDK 10 and it's located in the `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` folder on Windows.

Possible problems:

1. You installed JRE 10 only (instead of JDK 10). `jshell` is NOT part of the JRE.
2. `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` is not part of the `PATH` system variable.

See also: [Environment variables for java installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation)

Comment: JShell is part of JDK 9 and above

Comment: @Chinmoy, true; I've referred to the specific tag `java-10` in the question though. Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the `bin` folder of your Java Development Kit (JDK) installation to the `PATH` environment variable. The `java` command works, because the JRE installs a copy of the `java.exe` executable in `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\` and adds it to the `PATH`.

For editing the `PATH`, see [How do I set system environment variables in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10) on superuser

Comment: Thanks @Mark Rotteveel

Answer (score 2):

The same problem has happened to me.
Uninstall and Install the right JDK from Oracle website.

steps:
1. Control Panel > System & Security > System > Change Setting > Advance > Change Environment Variable > System Variable > New > Variable Name:"Path" & Variable Value: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin" (address of the bin)> ok

You are good to go.
Here's the link to the video that helped me.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UokTaTwckDw

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. I set `JAVA_HOME` and wrapped it with double quotes (`""`).

```
JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144"
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a JRE. You should install JDK and set `JAVA_HOME`. Then jshell will start working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Run you command prompt as Administrator. **window -> cmd -> Run as Administrator** then type jshell.

Answer (score 1):

Remove any default path variable that is set in envirnoment variables when you install JDK apart from JAVA_HOME.Then update your JAVA_HOME to /path of JDK 9 OR Above/

Answer (score 0):

**Two things to consider here:**

1. jshell is only incldued with jdk >9.0 so better to install latest LTS version of jdk (not same as JRE)
2. Need to have two environment variables set **JAVA_HOME** and **Path**

**JAVA_HOME** should point to where jdk is installed on your machine without bin folder

**Path** should point to bin folder of the installed jdk ( since jshell is present in the bin folder )

Hope this helps...