# Leiningen cannot find SDK

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm trying to install Leiningen from here https://djpowell.github.io/leiningen-win-installer/. But it cannot find SDK. If I check "Custom path" then it gives an out of range error on the next screen. Both Java and SDK are installed.

Comment: What's the error? And do you have Java on the system PATH?

Comment: Error: "An installed Java Developlent Kit could not be found automatically."

Comment: İf I continue, it asks "Select the path to a Java Development Kit for Leiningen to use." If I check "Custom Location" on the next screen, I get "Runtime Error (at28:618) Out of range."

Comment: How do I find if it is on the system path?

Comment: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Comment: I have this: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath

Comment: That looks wrong. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation

Comment: Or just run a Java installer. Usually it handles all that.

Comment: I ran a Java installer

Answer (score 1):

that installer automates these steps (from the project page)

> The installer makes curl.exe available so that leiningen can download and upgrade files.
>
> The installer downloads and installs the latest lein.bat from github.
>
> lein.bat is added to your PATH variable.
>
> LEIN_JAVA_CMD is set to point to your selected JDK, and the :java-cmd property is set in your user profile in profiles.clj.
>
> lein self-install is run to install the Leiningen JAR file.
>
> The uninstaller will remove the files that were installed, together with the Leiningen self-installs and search indexes; the environment variables that were set, and the additions to the PATH.

A likely area for this to do wrong is the setting of `LEIN_JAVA_CMD` and the `:java-cmd` key in the leiningen profile.clj file.

I'd first check:

- the java path is correct in the value of the `LEIN_JAVA_CMD` environment vatiable
- check the [profiles.clj file](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PROFILES.md#default-profiles) in your home dirctory for conflicting JRE paths
- uninstall that installer and do it by following the instructions at https://leiningen.org/

also note that Clojure only required the java runtime JRE and does not require or use the JDK. differing versions and paths between these has caused problems as well.