# How to edit environment variables In Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, minecraft

I am trying to mod Minecraft and the YouTube tutorial I'm watching is on Windows 10, I'm on Windows 8.1.

The thing is they're editing environment variables. So what? I think. They tell me to create a variable called JAVA_HOME, Done. 
So, the problem? They're editing the PATH variable, and they get a window coming up, and they add a variable to the multiple others there. But when I try to, It comes up with a single line that is already taken, so I can edit that.

At the moment I can`t mod it because of that reason. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the first answer here. [Environment variables for java installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation)

Make sure you resart your system for the system to recognize your environment variables changes.