# Codes not works until press the clean and build in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I work on a project using database. When i change some query change to get some values from the database **NetBeans IDE gives me past coding changes result. But if i press the Clean and Build the project it is working fine.** This consumes lot of my time.

How to fix this? Whenever i open NetBeans IDE it shows this dialog box

[image]

When i press "Yes" that opens the NetBeans IDE.

This started to happen after i changed the jdk version from 8 to 9. It seems NetBeans 8.1 does not work with jdk 9 so i again installed jdk 8.

After that install this message showing when i start NetBeans. I have no idea this is affect to above problem i have mentioned. So actually i have two problems.

i have installed jdk1.8.0_172 and i given environment variable correct path. but that is still same –

```
JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin
```

Comment: Cannot locate java installation its clear enough cross check your java home environment variable.

Comment: @JavaFan could you please explain more?

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation

Comment: i have install jdk1.8.0_172 and i give environment variable correct path. but that is still same

Comment: Variable Name : JAVA_HOME and Variable Value :  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve invalid home specifieid error in netbeans follow below instructions

**Go to C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\etc**

**Open the file netbeans.conf then change netbeans_jdkhome to the path of your JDK, netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172"**

Make sure **netbeans.conf run as administrator**.

If you are not sure about the version of jdk, you can find it by typing in CMD java -version