# Compiling a Java Servlet on toTomCat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I'm trying to follow an introductory tutorial on java servlets and tomcat setup. I have already set up tomCat and hosted an html file. now I'm trying to connevt my Java file which is located here: C:\myWebProject\tomcat\webapps\hello\WEB-INF\classes

the tutorial tells me to do the following:

```
// Assume that Tomcat is installed in c:\myWebProject\tomcat
```

// Change directory to the Java source directory
c:
cd \myWebProject\tomcat\webapps\hello\WEB-INF\classes

// Compile
javac -cp .;c:\myWebProject\tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar HelloServlet.java

but the compile command line does not work.. it tells me that javac is not a recognized command. I've tried replacing it with just java, but then I'm told "error could not find or load main class"

Sorry if the very noob question but I could not find anything helpful after googleing either

Comment: This looks like you only have a runtime environment (JRE) but not the development kit (SDK) installed. You need the DSK in order to compile things.

Comment: I do have SDK installed

Comment: Then I guess you have both SDK and JRE installed but your PATH variable is pointing to the JRE's ``bin`` folder.

Comment: I do have the correct path but it still does not recognize:
C:\Users\hen>path
PATH="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin;"(other paths)

C:\Users\hen>javac -version
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Probably you have wrong paths. Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation

Answer (score 1):

If you are having 'javac is not a recognized command' , it means your JAVA_HOME and path environment variables are not set.

Comment: still does not work.. here is my pack: C:\Users\hen>path
PATH="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin;"(other paths)

C:\Users\hen>javac -version
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.