# Stuck Trying to Compile .Java

Tags: java, javac

So I've been trying to figure out how to run .java files because I was trying to run someone's program and I've been researching solutions for sooo long

```
cd "directory with file trying to run"
set path=C:\Program Files\Java\my-java-version-or-whatever\bin
javac Test.java (<-- name of file)
```

also tried

```
SET JAVA_HOME
```

and that worked and showed a path but when I did javac again it still didn't work. All help is much appreciated!!

And for some reason it just keeps saying that javac is not recognized.

Comment: You just need to include java installation path till bin directory in PATH.

Comment: What did you set the JAVA_HOME to?

Comment: use below link to do.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation

Comment: @AnkurChrungoo I set it to C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191

Comment: @secretsuperstar C:\Users\Georg\Documents\CS and Code\Other People's Project\SnapsAuto-master\src\main\java

Comment: You need `jdk` for `javac`

Comment: @GeorgeDouj88 follow what secret superstar said

Comment: I suggest developing using an IDE. It will save you a lot of time in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install `JDK` on your machine and point the `JAVA_HOME` to the same.

Find JDK Installation Directory

Open the default installation path for the JDK:

There should be a subdirectory like:

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191

**Set the JAVA_HOME Variable**

*Once you have the JDK installation path:*

Right-click the My Computer icon on your desktop and select Properties.

Click the Advanced tab, then click the Environment Variables button.

Under System Variables, click New.

Enter the variable name as JAVA_HOME.

Enter the variable value as the installation path for the Java Development Kit.

Click OK.

Click Apply Changes.

Comment: how do you do that? I went to the link that spandey15 provided and did everything except for the last one because I didn't know what to do and I tried everything, even ran CMD as admin and it still didn't work

Comment: You cab download jdk 8 from here https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html and you are free choose any version you would like to.

Comment: What is the JAVA_HOME set?

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191

Comment: what is the result for `echo %JAVA_HOME%`

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191

Comment: This looks good enough. Hope you are not using multiple command prompts. one for setting `JAVA_HOME` and another for `javac`. The better can be done by updating environment variables. updating the answer with steps.

Comment: You need to restart the command line if you updated using steps given in answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have just set your JAVA_HOME make sure you restart your command console.